# When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?

Tags: support, faq, tags, tag-creation-process

> Can someone please create the tag [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) on Stack Overflow? We need to have it because...
>
> - *Foo* is a recent/upcoming release of a popular, established OS/language/framework
> - *Foo* is a hot new language/library
> - We're currently using some other tag for questions about *Foo*, but it's causing ambiguity with a separate thing that's also named *Foo*
> - Other conditions apply which would make [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) a reasonable tag to create

---

- **When is it appropriate to create a tag?**
- **Who can create a tag?**
- **What happens if a tag is disputed?**

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Related: [Tags should be reviewed before they are created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404893).

Comment: Related: [Best practices for tagging: a search engine optimization view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360814/best-practices-for-tagging-a-search-engine-optimization-view). The question *"Should we optimize the tags both for "connecting experts with questions" and for search engines to better index the questions?"* is upvoted, so **YES**.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

## When is it appropriate to create a tag?

Tags should be created only when there is a *clear need* for them. This is determined by considering the [two main purposes of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) as described below:

#### 1. Tags connect experts with questions they will be able to answer.

The most important purpose of a tag is to **connect** topical questions
to an audience of qualified answerers. This allows answerers that are knowledgeable in a given subject area to be connected to questions related to their area of expertise, and allows askers to more easily funnel their questions to said experts.

Thus, if a tag is created about something that no one can really be an "expert" in, it may not be a good tag. This is most obvious with so-called "[meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)," which are often very ambiguous and often describe the *nature* of a question rather than the *content* within the question. Examples of this include [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) and [hard-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-question).

#### 2. Tags sort questions into specific, well-defined categories.

Another purpose of tags is to **sort** questions about related subject areas into narrow, well-defined categories. This allows questions that are about similar subjects to be grouped together, which helps keep the site organized and aids in searching and finding related questions.

Keep in mind that new tags, by nature, won't be used by anyone else until other questions adopt the tag. If there's already a tag or tags in use that adequately describe the specific content of your question, you may not need to create a new tag.

## Who can create a tag?

Any user with at least [1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) may create a tag on Stack Overflow.

To do this, one must apply it directly to a new or existing question. This is done by typing the new tag into the question's tag field and then submitting the post or edit. The person who adds the new tag will be recorded as the creator of that tag.

**If you *do* have enough reputation to create the tag**, and if you think there is
a *clear need* for a tag, go ahead and create it yourself. Uncommon topics are perfectly valid for a tag, as long as they're still clearly defined. Make sure to submit at least an *excerpt* for the [tag wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) so others can see its intended use. If the new tag causes controversy, you can always come back to meta to ask the community to judge it and give some feedback.

**If you *do not* have enough reputation to create the tag**, then *add a comment* on your question asking for the new tag. Consider including a reason *why* you think this tag would be appropriate. If someone with enough reputation agrees with you, they will create the tag and add it to your question. Please delete your comment once this has happened.

As an alternative, you can request the creation of a tag by posting a question here on Meta, tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [tag-creation-request](/questions/tagged/tag-creation-request) (do not use the [tag-creation-process](/questions/tagged/tag-creation-process) tag for such requests). This gives other people in the community the opportunity to discuss if the new tag is needed. Note that **tags cannot exist without questions**. If there are no existing questions that the proposed tag can be added to, then the request cannot be fulfilled.

Your meta question to request a new tag must address at least the following
topics:

- Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate.
- Explain why the tag and such questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow.
- Provide an initial tag wiki **excerpt** and a tag wiki **description**
  for the new tag.

  - The main purpose of the tag wiki *excerpt* - also known as the user guidance - is to tell people what the tag should be used for. Its length is limited to ~500 characters, and it does not support Markdown.
  - The tag wiki *description* should stand alone as a detailed description of the tag, and should include all the information present in the excerpt. It can be much longer than the excerpt, and does support Markdown.
  - The excerpt is by far the more important of the two tag wikis - **no tag** should ever be created without an accompanying guide on how to use it.
  - More information on how to write a great tag wiki can be found in the [Tag Wiki FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe).
- Propose a good and fitting name for the tag.

  - Tag names can be made of lowercase letters, numbers, and a limited set of special characters (`. - + #`), and have a maximum length of 35 characters.

Please also note that a small number of tags [have been blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag) because they've been deemed specifically harmful; these tags are barred from the system and *cannot* be recreated.

## What happens if a tag is disputed?

Tags may be "disputed" if members of the community feel it is causing or leading to some kind of problem or harm. There are a number of reasons a tag can be disputed, which may lead to some form of further action:

- The tag itself is off-topic.

  - Eg. The tag [pepperoni-pizza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pepperoni-pizza) isn't related to programming or programming tools, and therefore is off-topic by nature.
- The tag is attracting off-topic questions.

  - Eg. The tag [music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/music) might describe the content of good questions, but it also attracts a lot of off-topic questions not about programming.
- The tag refers to the same topic as another tag.

  - Eg. The tags [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) and [dotnet-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnet-core) are alternate spellings referring to the same framework.

(This list is not exhaustive, and there may be exceptions in certain cases.)

Depending on the type of dispute, once some consensus is reached, action may be taken. This may include a variety of measures including "[burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)" (removal of a tag from all questions), "synonymization" (making a tag point to another tag, either [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) or via a moderator), merging tags, cleaning up questions within a tag, adjusting the tag's wiki, etc.

If you see a tag that doesn't seem to be clear, well-defined, and on-topic, or which seems to be causing problems, feel free to start a meta discussion about the tag to solicit input from the community regarding it.

## Related Reading

- [What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one) - Meta Stack Exchange FAQ
- [When should I create a new tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug) - Meta Stack Exchange FAQ
- [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions) - Meta Stack Exchange FAQ
- [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) - Stack Overflow Help Page
- [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) - Meta Stack Exchange FAQ

Comment: Is there a limitation/rule about how many questions about a topic should already exist before creating a tag for it? Background: I wrote a tool for programmers and just answered the first Stack Overflow question about it. I was thinking about creating a new tag with the name of my tool and adding it to that question...but at the moment, it's just *one* question.

Comment: @ChristianSpecht: then that's not really tag-worthy, yet. If there is going to be enough traffic for your tool, someone will create a tag for it; as a tool author it is probably best to leave this to the community.