# Crowfunding for reputation: teaming up to create a new tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, privileges

To create a tag on Stack Overflow, one needs 1500 reputation.

Some open-source communities would benefit from a Stack Overflow tag, but none of the members have this high amount of reputation.

However, together, they can gather enough reputations to create the tag.

I suggest to create a kind of "crowdfunding" mechanism for reputation in order to access certain privileges.

Comment: No, you can instead just ask for the tag on Meta, or put a comment on the questions mentioning that such a tag would be nice. See [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944)

Comment: Or a polite request inside the question itself (I think this should be tagged [tag:whatever] but I can't create tags myself).  Another user can edit in the tag if it makes sense and remove the request at the same time.

Comment: Generally though, we don't like brand tags (e.g. [tag:adobe] or [tag:microsoft]), so don't be surprised if high-rep users decline to add it.

Comment: I see this is your first meta post, so I just want to (preemptively) point out that [votes on `[feature-request]` posts express approval or disapproval of the feature being proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), not the quality of the post content. (Perhaps you already knew that, but many first-time posters don't.)

Answer (score 8):

No, I don't think that is a very good idea. Reputation should be a reward for one's ability as an asker/answerer, not a form of charity.

If a tag is really needed, all you need is for someone with 1500+ points to edit your question to include the tag.

If you really want to get together to obtain 1500 points, you could use the bounty system - but that would be abuse of the system, and is likely to bring you to the attention of a moderator for voting fraud. So I **don't** recommend it!

Occassionally people have asked on Meta if a specific tag could be created. But we don't create tags for the sake of having tags; we create them when they are needed. If you have a question that would really benefit from a specific tag, you can raise the issue on Meta.

In general, if you feel that something should be done but don't have the privileges to do it, state your case on Meta or perhaps on chat. Make sure you can back up your idea, and be open to other people's opinions - as always on SE.

Comment: I don't think this is what is being asked.  I think he's asking for the ability of two 750 rep people to be able to create the tag.