# Is there a place for Web developers in the community?

Tags: discussion

Is there a place in the community to ask questions on web development packages, components etc? Nothing seems to fit what I'm looking for (open source stores, cms techniques, Wordpress, Rapidweaver)

Comment: Try: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: webmasters is helpful, but why would there be an SE site for wordpress, when there are not sites for other similar tools?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte They either have beta versions or don't have enough backers. See http://area51.stackexchange.com/ for all proposed sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the titular question: **Yes, definitely.** We have plenty of very active web development tags; [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) are *huge*.

To answer your body question; it appears you are asking about website creation through a *tool* as opposed to writing the code yourself. In general, these topics would be off-topic for Stack Overflow, but if you have a question about programming *within* that tool, go right ahead!

Comment: Thanks for that. Some of these tools - like Rapidweaver, or yikes, Dreamweaver, or Coda - are really IDEs. So I guess in the sense that Xcode is a tag in SO, could some of these tools be tagged? Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte They would need to be created by asking an applicable; on-topic question where the use of that tag would be appropriate. 1500+ rep users can create the tags. If you have such a question, I would be happy to look at it and add the tag. Just make sure the question is actually *specific to the tool*. If its general javascript, a dreamweaver tag won't mean anything.

Comment: Thanks for your offer Bradley. Much appreciated. I will keep it in mind.. (and frame a better question next time).

Comment: @DavidDelMonte For a bit more info; heres the tag creation FAQ post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work