# I am a user of a MATLAB library that lacks wide documentation. Am I encouraged to create a tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, due to my current occupation, I have been widely using the "open source" MATLAB library [EIDORS](http://eidors3d.sourceforge.net/). It is a quite specific library of the fields of [electrical impedance tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance_tomography) (EIT) and [diffuse optical tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_optical_tomography), that are not the most common tomographic techniques around.

The software is quite nice, and it has implemented quite complex algorithms very useful in the field, but it lacks documentation. There are just a few non-consistent examples of very different algorithms without any link/reference/explanation (most of them) and the "browse docs" link just redirects you to a page where the headers of the .m (MATLAB) files are highlighted.

At the moment I can use the software a an average user (I guess), but it makes me think that I would totally liked to have a Stack Overflow-like question place to ask my newbie (and not that newbie) questions about it when I was learning. So the thought of opening a new tag on Stack Overflow has crossed my mind several times. I think that if I would open it and ask/answer some questions on Stack Overflow about the topic, lost EIDORS users will start asking more questions and having useful information somewhere.

Note that I totally understand that the documentation is not strong for this library as they are maintained by very few people and the topic is not extremely wide around the world, so creating an own forum would be very time consuming for the maintainers.

So after all the waffling around my question:

By the mighty rules of Stack Overflow: **Am I encouraged to start asking and answering some basic questions about the library, opening a tag about it (`EIDORS`)? Or as it is a quite narrow field/library it won't be of much benefit for the "internets".**

Another concern I have is that if I start opening questions and posting answers about it I may be seen as an "upvote vampire", and I definitely am not thinking of doing this for that reason!

Comment: Well, you don't actually get any rep for answering your own questions, so there's that. Also, there's a tag for `date-of-birth` so I don't know that the rules for tag creation are all that serious.

Comment: @BSMP Indeed the rules for tag creations are quite weak. I could create the tag `bananas` if I want (as I have >1500 rep), but I am asking more "should I?" than "can I?".

Comment: I would do a search for EIDORS as text and see how many questions there are on it.  If there's 1 or 2, maybe not (yet).  If there's dozens its probably tag worthy.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have only found 1. But that is literally the reason I haven't ask any of my questions about it is SO. The reason I would create the tag and some questions/answers would be to encourage people to ask!

Comment: The tag should be added after the questions exist (as a way to group them), not before as a way to try to attract them, IMO.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: @BSMP You do get rep for answering your own questions (but not for _accepting_ them -- only from votes by other users).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - Thanks for the correction. This also makes an earlier conversation make more sense.

Comment: Have you considered jumping in and writing a bit of documentation for that project (if they accept contributions)? That would seem a more obvious place to put documentation than on SO.

Comment: @deceze Indeed that'd be the logical step, but they have zero support for new contributions and they are very very proud of their code (which makes is a bit hard to criticize). They have a help mailing list where they are... not as polite and helpful as SO. I would not be thinking of this option if contributing to EIDORS was easy (or even possible).

Comment: And SO is already being critiqued for being rude at times... that's saying something. ;o)

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, I agree with that. My question is: Should I create several questions about the topic and add a new tag with them? Is that behaviour encouraged? I don't want to just create a tag!

Comment: I agree with @deceze: Write your own doc and publish it in your own, fork in github so anyone can improve it easily, and leave the creators deal with it. At the end, if they like the doc they'll point it to you, or copy/improve/adapt it. And you'll have something nice for you and newbies, XD.

Comment: I vote for creating the tag, as long as there is one question--perhaps your own.  And ask whatever questions you want--you don't have to ask questions specifically to promote the tag.  I agree with you, Ander, to an extent.  The existence of tag per se doesn't promote questions.  But once an EIDORS user sees one question, and realizes that there's a tag, s/he can then search for others.  That increases the community of people who focus on those questions, and thus promotes the tag and the community, indirectly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the tag, just create your questions and answers on the library and see how they are received. If there is interest create more and see how things go from there. When there are a reasonable number of questions on the topic creating a tag is perfectly natural, but creating a tag to encourage questions doesn't make sense in my opinion.

Don't let the presence or absence of a tag determine whether you post questions/answers, that is the wrong way to go about it. Tags don't determine what is on- or off-topic, the topics of your questions/answers do.

Comment: As a complement, whereas explicitly allowed (and even encouraged) self-answered question are sometimes not well received by users that ignore that (or simply disagree with that). May I suggest to not post several questions in a short amount of time ? For the same reason, don't be discouraged by occasional down-votes or bad comments...

Comment: This answer is interesting. However, it is quite normal that people get disencouraged to ask questions about at topic that is inexistent in a certain site. I have been reluctant to post EIDORS questions myself, and I am a common SO user. This makes me think that if you are not a signed user of SO and you have a question about it, you'd never ask it in here as you may think that no one would answer anything. But in general this is a quite good advice.

Comment: I speak only for myself, but I do not feel that the discouragement you speak of is necessarily "quite normal". Personally I have never had any qualms about asking programming-related questions on SO, regardless of the programming sub-topic. Questions about EIDORS are programming questions, and "programming" is certainly a topic that is existent on this site. Just ask away. If there's not tag for it, just tag it [tag:matlab]. If somebody feels like creating a tag for it they will. If you have enough rep to create a tag then make one. It's pretty open, don't overthink it!

Comment: (Besides, correctly tagged questions, especially from new users, are relatively rare because many users don't pay attention to tags, and also the tag field is at the *bottom* of the ask page. I would guess that most people asking questions are *not* checking tags first before writing questions, certainly not enough for lack of tag to be intimidating or presence of tag to attract.)

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about fingers being pointed at you, because I just created the tag. I'm to blame.

The help center doesn't say that tags should not be created for narrow fields. A tag has to start somewhere somehow. And if it starts with the first question, so be it.

[Now please edit the tag wiki to explain what this library does.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eidors/info)

If you want to post answers to your own questions, but don't want the fame, you can turn them into community wikis. [The help center clearly states that this is one reason to create them:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)

> **When should I make my answers Community Wiki?**
>
> When you feel your post would benefit from less concern about voting
>   affecting the reputation of those participating in it.

Comment: This tag has 1 question (with no accepted answer) and only 2 followers... I feel like this tag shouldn't have been created for exactly the reasons specified by other answers here!