# How to create new tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation-process

I would like to post a question for NodeOS, but I didn't find this tag.  How do I create the new tags?

Comment: Notice, that unless is something strongly tied to a programing task, your question would be very likely be closed. Just tagging node.js should be enough most (always) of the times.

Comment: What is this NodeOS you speak of?

Answer (score 16):

Users over 1500 reputation can create tags. You can't.

They simply type the name of the new tag into the "tags" line of the question create/edit form. This results a confirmation popup, after accepting that the tag is created.

(And tags not having question will be automatically removed in a day.)

P.s. post a comment below your question with your request, I am sure around the first visitor over 1500+ will do what you want.

Comment: yes, you have to get 1500+ reputation

Comment: This answer and the preceding comment are both severely deficient. To initiate
the creation of a new tag by **suggesting** it, all it takes is a mere 5 in
reputation. See the procedure described as
["you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new **meta discussion**"
](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945) and the five bullets of that answer
which are required to be diligently pursued.