# tag creation to distinguish between 2 kinds of virtual machines

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation, tag-creation-process

As a programmer interested by some fundamental notions, I have subscribed to the [virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) tag to get the questions concerning the implementation of virtual machines (like the JVM, self-made VMs to study the basis in CS courses, or interpreters / emulators ).

But there is a daily bunch of SO questions regarding infrastructure / networking virtual machines like Docker, Azure, Amazon cloud services, and many others that I don't care at all.

1. In many cases the question is only a general networking / configuration that is more suited for SuperUser or ServerFault (i cannot ping / open ssh session, ...) and [c|s]hould could be migrated.
2. in lesser cases the question is related to the automation / management of VMs by code (for automatic creation, monitoring) and is legit for SO. Questions addressing the usage of a VM to host a development box (e.g to bea able to use XCode from a PC) might be included. Or not.
3. in few cases it is a question on the implementation of a VM

I plea for a disambiguation of the cases 2) and 3) and I am willing to help in the creation of a different tag and re-tagging of questions that are true VM coding questions.

**Edit**: like suggested by @steve I propose:

- the creation of [vm-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vm-implementation) or [virtual-machine-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine-implementation) with a description that it is reserved to implementation / coding level questions
- the creation of [vm-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vm-management) or [virtual-machine-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine-management) or maybe [virtual-machine-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine-automation) to catch the scripting of VMs
- as [virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) states "A virtual-machine is software emulating complete computer hardware. There are various applications that supply this functionality." we could keep it for general questions addressing the virtualization domain

What do you think?

Comment: Want to propose tag names? Maybe virtual-machine-implementation vs virtual-machine-management?

Comment: @SteveBennett: your suggestion makes sense, I have updated my question to follow it

Comment: @Seki: aren't those tag names too long? I thought they could only be up to 25 characters long.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I do not create tags usually, so i am unaware of such technical restriction. But the faked tag buttons in my question seem to work properly... Shorter names suggestion is welcome if needed.

Comment: If the questions are off-topic, then people asking them are very unlikely to use the correct tag. It's probably better for you to ignore tags that frequently appear on these off-topic questions. That way you can either hide them via your preferences or vote to close them.

Comment: @BilltheLizard there are indeed lots of questions for the virtual-machine tag that are actually off-topic and deserve a simple migration to serverfault / superuser. I don't even understand why so many of them get answer here as no coding is involved but in many cases only networking / administration knowledge. By creating a new tag reserved for programmation the new VM questions could be better distinguished and I could subscribe to that new tag instead of the former.

Comment: form the suggested related questions, I see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/317266) that I could just go ahead and add that new tag to the coding question, but I would like to see if there is some *a priori* acceptance

Comment: I have eventually created the vm-implementation tag and started to retag some questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that [virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) explicitly address the emulation of a whole computer, and that there is also [jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvm) dedicated for the Java Virtual Machine

- for questions actually on design and implementation of a virtual machine (interpreter, Turing machine, automaton) replace [virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) by the new [vm-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vm-implementation)
- for questions both on [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine), replace [virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) (or both) by the dedicated [jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvm) if *ad-hoc*