# Create the [apache-traffic-server] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

The other day, I noticed a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681749) dealing with [Apache Traffic Server](https://trafficserver.apache.org/). Yet it was tagged as [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) and [traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traffic), which obviously does not fit. In the absence of a better match, I would suggest creation of [apache-traffic-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-traffic-server), since there are [numerous SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=apache+traffic) concerning it.

And yes, I read the [standard faq entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944) on tag creation: Since I have less than 1,5K reputation, could someone please create it for me?

Comment: [Looks like that's not the only question about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=apache+traffic+server+is%3Aquestion) That returns 700+ results currently. Naturally, some could be false positives.

Comment: The real question is... a traffic tag?! BTW, I read the description of Apache Traffic Server and I'm having issues seeing how it fits inside the scope of SO...

Comment: @braiam So you'd rather have such questions migrated to Server Fault?

Comment: If they are about "managing information technology systems in a business environment", of course. [They have a tag for it, at very least](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache-traffic-server), each of the 5 questions with answers.

Comment: I didn't know Apache Traffic Server was a thing. Seems sensible to me, tag created and wiki edit put into the queue.

Comment: @halfer Thanks a lot. Looks like you have just started assigning it as well. I will try and keep in mind that questions tagged as such _might_ be better off at Server Fault.

Comment: No probs. I assigned just the one you referred to, though I agree with @Kendra that some new tag re-assignments would be in order.