# Tag creation request: "windows-uwp" for Universal Windows Platform apps

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, tag-creation-process

As I don't have enought privileges to do so, I'm asking this question.

Microsoft Windows 10 introduce the new Universal Windows Platform.

This is a good time to use a new tag to specify xaml request for the new platform.

As everybody knows, "xaml" tag per se, without other more specific tags has been a real mess because can be used in many different context: as a language in WPF, Silverlight, Windows Phone Silverlight, and also as a framework in Windows 8.x Phone and Store app.

I do think we need a programming tag to specify questions related to the new Universal Windows Platform.

Can someone that has the needed privileges make a request for tag creation?

Comment: Do we already have question where those can be used?

Comment: And anyway, are you sure they are actually useful? Also, why should they be this cryptic and short?

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @Hans Passant: There are many more references to UWP on dev.windows.com and blogs.windows.com. Presumably UAP was deemed too generic.

Comment: windows-universal is too generic because it's used for Windows 8.x Universal Apps that are quite different than Universal Windows Apps. (Ok, we all know that Microsoft is less than perfect on choosing names...)
My request was aimed to help sort and easily identify question related to UWA. If uwa is too generic, I'd go for windows-uwa.

Comment: @rene: thanks for the link, I didn't know about that when I started this question. Good point. I'll reiterate my request whenever I'll find questions about UWA.

Comment: After more reading on Microsoft documentation, I've found that UWA is not a good choice, because "Universal Windows App" is also used for Windows 8.x kind of projects.
The only disambiguous way is "Universal Windows Platform apps" and I do agree with @Passant, the only acronim used is UWP.
So the only tag I still request is "windows-uwp".
Sorry for the mess.

Comment: Consider editing/updating the post to reflect the latest request. Without reading all comments and the answer, your request is still read as requesting 'uwp' tag.

Comment: I've edited my question, please remove down-vote if that was the cause. thanks

Comment: What's wrong with [tag:Windows-10]?

Comment: @TylerH: There may be issues specific to Windows 10 that affect non-universal apps.

Comment: @BoltClock I thought the whole paradigm of Windows 10 was that it was the same OS for every device, so all apps are "universal".

Comment: @TylerH: Well, we'll still have to deal with traditional desktop apps, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have at least two tags for this, [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) and [windows-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal) (which, for whatever reason, aren't synonyms yet). UWP is commonly used to stand for Universal Windows Platform, but I don't know if having [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) as a synonym of these tags will cause any confusion as I'm not sure if there are any other uses of this initialism (how about [windows-uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-uwp) instead? Typing "uwp" will still auto-complete to that).

Comment: Yes, windows-uwp will be great :-)