# What's the difference between the uwp and the win-universal-app tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Both tags seem to refer to the [Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx) framework. Or is there some difference between them? (If not - should one be burninated?)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298557/tag-creation-request-windows-uwp-for-universal-windows-platform-apps

Comment: [win-universal-app] was created for Windows 8.1 Universal apps. It looks like [someone changed the wiki excerpt to refer to Windows 10 and not WinRT 8.1 and it was approved](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23268371/revisions). I'm pretty sure that edit should have been rejected as you don't simply redefine a tag completely by changing its wiki.