# Revert tag synonym voting on UWP

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

As we can't start a discussion on synonym proposals on the tag itself (I think), I thought to do it here on meta.

The tag [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) has its origins when Microsoft announced the possibility to develop a universal app for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. This is also mentioned on the tag itself:

> You can build an app for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 at the same
>   time, and share code, user controls, styles, strings and other assets
>   between them. This reduces the expense associated with building and
>   maintaining an app for each type of device.
>
> If you already have a Windows Store app, you can easily add support
>   for a Windows Phone Store app. Similarly, if you start by creating a
>   Windows Phone app, you can easily add support for a Windows Store app.

However the subtitle text says it's for Windows 10:

> Windows Universal Apps are those apps which are developed at the same
>   time to target all Windows 10 platforms, including desktop, mobile,
>   Xbox, and IoT.

Usage for this tag has been reasonable but is declining lately in favor for [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp).

[image: Tag usage]

[image: Tag usage UWP]

The tag [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) correctly states it is for Windows 10, without any mention of previous versions.

> The Universal Windows Platform is a common platform for all devices
>   running Windows 10. The UWP is separated into device families like PC,
>   Mobile, IoT and many more. The UWP allows you to use common code for
>   all device families.

UWP is also the official naming used by Microsoft: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894631.aspx), [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples)

My issue now is that [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) is proposed as a synonym for [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) and will thus lose part of it's meaning. I see 2 possible (imho correct) solutions:

- Propose the synonym relation ship in the other direction, with [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) being master (which can't happen until the current is declined).
- Reject the synonym and keep [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) for 8.1 (and remove any reference to Windows 10, even state that [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) should be used for Windows 10.

I could have just edited the tags and push my opionion, but I think it's worth a discussion first.

---

Note: I don't mind doing the major part of the initial cleanup (and keeping an eye on it in the future) if the community opts for the 2nd option.

Edit:
Seems like there's already a [windows-10-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-universal) as well now, but I can't add it to UWP as a synonym.
[image]

Comment: I vote for

• Reject the synonym and keep win-universal-app for 8.1 (and remove any reference to Windows 10, even state that uwp should be used for Windows 10.

Comment: How about renaming [win-universal-app] to [windows-8.1-universal]? Note that someone haphazardly edited its excerpt while completely ignoring the main text.

Comment: Don't like the rename proposal... because the technology naming (although the OS version is implied) should not be tied to the OS version. Because if we do that, UWP should be UWP-10.

Comment: Making [uwp] a synonym of [win-universal-app] would mess up some things. It's true that many answers from universal apps will suit uwp questions, but there are many changes and enhancements in new platform, then I agree with @Depechie that the synonym proposal should be rejected.Though taking a look at newest questions seems that people sometimes doesn't differentiate those two platforms, therefore maybe name change would be a good idea? In other case, it would require (probably constant) tag editing.

Comment: @Depechie: The Universal Windows Platform is specific to Windows 10. There is no such platform on Windows 8.1. In particular, UWP apps *cannot run* on Windows 8.1. So, whether you like it or not, these technologies *are* OS version-specific.

Comment: @BoltClock hmm that is not 100% correct. Windows-universal-apps was universal but for win8.1 but still run on win10. So why would we add OS version to it? Same for uwp, that came out for win10 but I bet for the 'next' big win version they still will be able to run. In other words the OS version is indeed implicit tied, I was talking about not adding them to the tag.

Comment: @Depechie: Windows 8.1 Universal apps are not UWP apps...

Comment: True, never said they were. But they are universal ( that name was already used during win8.1 but meant targeting phone and desktop at that time. Universal now means all win10 os )

Comment: This is exactly why there's a confusion under the SO users in using these tags correctly :) While 8.1 can run on 10 (as a bonus), you typically want to use 10 UWP for dev targetted on 10.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't seen anyone use [uwp] to describe questions about WinRT 8.1 code. I don't see a problem with the tag name [uwp] as it is.

Comment: The problem is not with [uwp] but with [windows-universal] witch seems to be used instead of [uwp] and may bring some confusion. As I think renaming can be needed here (I don't like it much, but it seems to be lesser evil) - as it is now, if someone puts tag [win-univarsal-app] it's not clear for me if he asks for WinRT 8.1 or W10.

Comment: What worries me is that Visual Studio is showing UWP apps as simply "Universal Windows" (whereas former universal apps are rebranded as "Universal Windows 8.1". From there, when asking a question, I'll naturally type "Universal" in the tag box, and pick "win-universal-app" ("uwp" doesn't even appear in the search). Moreover, most of the knowledge from Win8 apps still applies to Win10 apps. So I'm more into platform-specific categories, as was done for Windows Phone ([tag:Windows-Phone], [tag:Windows-Phone-7], [tag:Windows-Phone-8]), with [tag:UWP] being a synonym of [tag:win-universal-app-10]

Comment: @KooKiz as you mentioned, it's Universal Windows (Platform). That alone is enough for me to make UWP the master and a possible win-universal-app-10 a synonym. It's universal windows, not the other way round. The question then is, does UWP show up in the tag box if it has the synonym to make the search trigger? (Maybe a mod knows)

Comment: @Bart A simple test shows that it does. Type "wp8" as tag when asking a question, and it will find "Windows-Phone-8". So indeed the solution could just be to add a synonym to disambiguate (be it win-universal-app-10, or universal-windows-platform, or really just anything as long as it has the word "universal" in it

Comment: If we make old 8.1 questions [tag:windows-8.1-universal] then *uwp* can be a synonym of *win-universal-app*. It will also fit to [tag:windows-10-universal], which also looks nice as we have: [tag:windows-10], [tag:windows-10-mobile]. There will be platform specific universal apps, and user should point which he addresses, the situation like with other tags on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the uwp and the win-universal-app tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306807/whats-the-difference-between-the-uwp-and-the-win-universal-app-tags)

Comment: Can we please have the **uwp** tag back?! The *win-universal-app* tag is so confusing. When we talk about the new universal apps that run on all Windows 10 devices, we always refer them as UWP apps. The same #uwp tag is widely used on Twitter as well.

Comment: Between Mar 31 and today - exactly 2 weeks - there have been ~250 uses of [uwp] remapped to [win-universal-app]. Just sayin'.

Comment: With about 350 uses (inter/extrapolated week/month use) of the [win-universal-app] tag, 250 remappings is a lot. Proving my point we need uwp. Go use some mod powers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past month, there have been ~600 uses of [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) remapped to [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app), and only a couple hundred or so uses of the actual [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) tag. I have no idea if anyone is even sure what [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) is supposed to mean when they add that tag to their own question, but I sure as hell hope that [when someone says UWP, they actually mean UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22uwp%22%20is%3aquestion).

I'm not going to repeat the discussion that's already taken place in the comments, but I'm going to perform a little experiment: I've deleted the master-synonym relationship for the time being, and I will continue to monitor how many questions are posted with the [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) and [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) tags respectively. I'll also sort through the [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) questions to see which ones pertain to UWP only, which ones pertain to Windows 8.1 Universal only, and which ones are a combination of both. I'll report back in a month with my findings and then we can decide on the next step.

The effects of deleting the master-synonym relationship are:

- New questions tagged [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) posted starting from today will keep [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp).
- New questions tagged [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) posted starting from today will keep [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app).
- Questions posted prior to today had any and all uses of [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) remapped to [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app); those questions will keep [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) as the synonym is never stored in the database during the lifetime of the master-synonym relationship.

  This, incidentally, is why having a master-synonym relationship pointing to [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) as the master was problematic: it made it exceedingly difficult to track which questions were UWP-specific and which ones were specific to Windows 8.1 (especially considering many features specific to UWP *simply don't exist* on older platforms, the entire reason why UWP is even a thing).

Note that none of the existing questions have been modified by this change; it's purely cosmetic for existing questions and will only affect questions posted starting from today.

Based on Romasz's answer to this question, as well as their other post on the topic [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312041/lets-end-confusion-between-win-universal-app-and-uwp), I'm going to guess that a significant portion of new questions with [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) will continue to refer to UWP, in which case we can re-establish a synonym, except in reverse, with [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) as the master instead, as it's much more widely recognized by the community and Microsoft. But again we'll decide what to do *after* I've collected some new data.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I have been hoping for since months. Pretty confident that the community will show this was the right decision to make.

Comment: Thanks for finding time to take a look at the problem. During experiment: 1) Should we retag newly added question with bad tag (uwp/win-universal-app) respectively to correct one? 2) Should we add uwp/universal tag to old questions from universal/uwp, if it fits there (answers questions)?

Comment: I've been following this topic in the past 2 weeks and I too suport Bart in his proposal to make UWP the main win 10 universal tag. Just in the past few days, I've seen a lot of confusion with the 'win-universal-app' tag with at least 3 win 8 related questions. There are also a lot of Win10 questions that do not have the 'uwp' tag which makes things very confusing both for asking questions and answering them.

Answer (score 6):

Taking a look at top three questions of [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) shows that users more likely use it for new W10 (UWP) apps than the [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) tag itself. This is probably in most cases caused by the reason mentioned by [KooKiz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311190/revert-tag-synonym-voting-on-uwp#comment277260_311190) - if you start typing *universal* in tag box, it will show everything but [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp). Therefore it will at least be needed to create new tag with *universal* in it's name and make it synonym of [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) to make it visible in the box.

The other case is that the tag [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) (or [windows-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal) which is the synonym) suits well for *UWP*, as it is also used in Visual Studio when creating new project (what is also mentioned in comments above). The only problem may be with some old questions that concern only *Windows 8.1 Universal* projects. In this case I think a good solution may be what [BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311190/revert-tag-synonym-voting-on-uwp#comment276313_311190) has suggested - change the tag name for old questions.

Taking into account all of this, my proposal is to:

- retag old questions concerning strictly *Windows 8.1 Universal* to what *Bart* has suggested [windows-universal-8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal-8.1). If a question still is actual for *UWP* then leave it with actual tag.
- make [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) and [windows-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal) synonyms of [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) or vice-versa (I'm not sure if it makes a difference),
- after this probably there will be no more need to create new tag [windows-universal-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal-platform), which seems to be little too long.

What do you think?

Comment: [tag:windows-8.1-universal] or [tag:windows-universal-8.1]. I'd say the 2nd option.

Comment: There are over 1500 questions (most of them back from 8.1 I suppose), retagging them all would be a big task. I think it's faster to rename the tag, remove it from the new uwp questions, and create a new [tag:win-universal-app] as synonym for [tag:uwp] indeed. So in the end we'll have [uwp] for 10 (in line with Microsoft naming on MSDN) and [tag:windows-universal-8.1] as main tags.

Comment: @Bart 2000 questions is not that much if there are few of us I think, also we don't have to do it one day/week. I'm also not sure if renaming the tag in our situation doesn't mean retagging all questions (maybe mods can do something more). But you may be right that retagging all and then removing *uwps* to their own tag may be faster. I also think now, if we shouldn't have a tag [tag:windows-universal-10] instead of [tag:windows-universal] - what in case in upcoming year MS releases UWP-11? Another retagging?

Comment: From [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag) I conclude that a rename by a mod is better than mass retagging. If Microsoft ever goes for UWP-11 ("v10 is last windows version" they said), we simply request a rename of UWP to UWP-10.

Comment: @Bart After some thinking I'm not sure what will require more work - to retag all to 8.1 and then to retag all questions that suit for *UWP* (probably most of them), or to leave the tag, make synonym and retag old 8.1 concertnig questions. I also like [tag:windows-universal-8.1] better.

Comment: Ahh... After the rename now [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/win-universal-app/topusers) shows that I only answered 25 *win-universal-app* tagged questions. All my *uwp* tagged answers are gone...

Comment: Do we now actually need to manually update tags in questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088500/adaptivetrigger-and-datatemplate/32092547#32092547) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108362/adding-a-swipe-gesture-to-open-splitview-pane/32110867#32110867)? :(

Comment: @JustinXL Hmm, I haven't checked my votes, but taking a look at yours I'm a bit confused. I thought that when tag synonym is added, the votes will be recalculated. Have you searched for similar question/case on meat or thought about asking such question?

Comment: So you have to wait until they are merged... See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318009/answers-tagged-with-synonyms-are-not-included-in-topusers-result/318011#318011).

Comment: @JustinXL Following [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316850/2681948), I wonder if they have some procedure for this - for example if tag synonym has been approved and 3 months after there haven't been protests, it's being merged. Let's wait if any moderator joins conversation at your meta question. Have you found a method to list question only from UWP tag?

Comment: Yeah let's hope that's the case. No I haven't found any. :(

Comment: I'm considering swapping the synonyms so [win-universal-app] points to [uwp] at the very least. This won't affect anything in the database - only the UI will display [uwp] instead after swapping. Anyone coming across [uwp] questions on Windows 8.1 Universal questions where the tag isn't relevant can then retag it I guess. My only concern is that, while UWP questions are growing by the day (see my latest comment on the OP), the number of Windows 8.1 Universal questions isn't insignificant either.

Comment: @BoltClock IMHO it would be a good change - the MS uses *uwp* widely, so for a site like SO there should be a tag like this, especially that this seems to be the future and number of questions will be growing. As you have mentioned questions regarding 8.1 could be tagged for example with *windows-8.1-universal* - I'm not only sure if people don't decide to tag *windows-8.1* and *uwp*, so the question gets bigger audience. After swapping: if user seraches for something with *uwp* - will it also point to questions with old *win-universal-app*? As I understand the tag will remain in old questions

Comment: Yes, it will point to old questions with the old tag. It should be OK to retag such questions with [windows-8.1-universal] as you come across them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that [uwp] isn't actually new.  It is just a marketing term from Microsoft, it is [winrt] with a different name.  Primarily important because WinRT was a pretty big dud and widely ignored.  Much like [win-universal-app], first used in Windows 8.1 and a very clumsy way to get a project to run both on a desktop and a phone.  And the very poorly named [windows-rt], an even bigger dud and everybody forgot what it meant after a few months.

That's all been worked on, Microsoft does forever need 3 versions to get it right.  UWP is the new name, still pretty poorly defined because it isn't U at all.  Only one implementation is currently available, Windows 10.  The phone version is still in beta and will be for a while.  Pretty unlikely they can revive ARM slates again.

Anybody that had a Store or Universal app that used to run on Windows 8.x or Phone is pretty likely to migrate, it isn't difficult.  Many questions in [winrt] or [win-universal-app] are very likely to be relevant to [uwp] programmers since the core api and the design tools are the same.  So trying to stop synonym voting is probably not a great idea.

Comment: I agree it boils down to the WinRT framework, but as you mention it's a new version. Writing apps (universal or not) for 8.1 and 10 is different enough to each deserve their own tag. I've already answered questions "incorrect" because the Q was tagged [tag:uwp] and afterwards the OP commented my answert that he needed it for 8.1.

Comment: That will always be around, remarkable for example how many questioners want a .NET 2.0 answer but don't mention that.  I usually just post a link to the careers site :)