# Let's end confusion between win-universal-app and uwp

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

With the release of Windows 10, Microsoft starts calling apps for that platform as *Universal Windows Platform* apps (UWP). We have a [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) tag for this, which is short and nice. The problem is that most users either use [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) or combine both of them. That's probably because when you type 'universal' in tag box, you will see [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) and [windows-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-universal) (which is the synonym).

The [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) has been used since Microsoft presented *Windows Universal* apps (Windows 8.1), also called as *Windows Store* apps. They are little different, but large amount of answers also fit to new UWP apps, as they also use Runtime API.

On the other hand, if we treat [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) as simply targeting multiple types of devices, then it perfectly fits for W8.1, as well as W10. The only thing users should do, is to add additional tag [windows-8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8.1)/[windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10), what is being practiced already. What is more, if the question fits for both platforms, then it can be tagged just by [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app). Also it will be easier for users to find old answer from W8.1, that will solve their problem in W10.

What is more if you create a new project in VS, you will see that Microsoft uses Universal Windows for both 8.1 and 10 platforms.

So here is what I think we should do:

- finish voting for synonym in [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/win-universal-app/synonyms),
- burninate (edit tags) [windows-10-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-universal) - there are only about 70 questions there, the tag IMHO is little too long, and most of questions use it along with [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) and/or [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app). Once we have universal tag, and user adds windows tag, we don't need this any more,
- burninate [windows-8.1-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8.1-universal) - the same sitation here, (I've always dreamed about taxonomist badge, but probably not this time...)

Comment: Didn't you suggest `[windows-8.1-universal]` a while back? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311371 ;-P

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, (I've even created that tag :), as an opposite to [tag:windows-10-universal]. Nevertheless I think they are not needed in case we have *win-universal-app* and *windows-10/windows-8.1*. Most of questions has those tags.