# Should my reputation for a tag include reputation for synonyms of that tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, reputation, tag-synonym-process

I have gathered reputation by answering questions tagged with [storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storm) (27 rep) and [apache-storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-storm) (25 rep).  I have no doubt that there is some overlap, but shouldn't there be a way to see/display the rep from the union of those tags, as well as from any other known tag synonyms?  Otherwise I'd claim that the leaderboards and topic badges, while factually correct, are misleading as to the top contributing users for a given multi-synonym topic.

Comment: [storm] is a synonym of [apache-storm], but obviously was never merged by a mod, nor were all the questions tagged [storm] you answered before the synonym edited yet. Still, I would consider not merging them for all purposes but possible breaking of the synonym a bug.

Comment: Agreed, it makes very little sense for the leader boards not to be merged.  Lots of nasty little corner cases no doubt, awarding badges in particular, so don't get your hopes up.

Comment: There is, as far as I can tell, only [one leaderboard](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-storm/topusers) for the [apache-storm] tag, since [storm] is a synonym of that one. Indeed, when you click on the [tag:storm] tag, you get redirected to the [tag:apache-storm] tag page, the expected behavior for a synonym. Even the questions in your profile that you've supposedly gotten rep for answering with a [storm] tag are actually tagged [apache-storm], so it looks like the tag rep data in the profile is bugged.

Comment: @Cody That's just because the link takes you to search which will replace the synonym, so all the posts from both tags will be mixed together.

Comment: @ani Okay, but then when I look at the [storm] questions he's listed as earning rep for answering (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1442874+[storm]), almost all of them don't have a [storm] tag at all. They've been retagged with [apache-storm]. So is the profile information just stale, having been cached when he earned the votes and the questions were still tagged [storm]?

Comment: @Cody I just performed the merge a few minutes ago, but I was able to find the ones tagged with storm just fine before I did that. You need to do [apache-storm] -[apache-storm] which will find all posts under the master tag and then exclude any that don't have that actual tag. Now we just have to wait for the tag scores to be recalculated again because of the merge.

Comment: Obviously I don't understand the tagging system or the search feature. A query like `[apache-storm] -[apache-storm]` makes absolutely no sense. You can't seriously be pretending that it does.

Comment: It doesn't. It's a bit of a workaround since the system doesn't provide any direct way to search for tags which have become synonyms - it always remaps it to the master tag.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Welcome to the world of tag synonyms.

Comment: @animuson *You need to do [apache-storm] -[apache-storm] which will find all posts under the master tag and then exclude any that don't have that actual tag* Does this not work now?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No.

Theoretically if a synonym still hasn't been merged, it means the tag hasn't been fully vetted. Two things could still happen:

- The synonym gets removed, identifying that the tag is in fact not a synonym.
- The tag gets cleaned up (questions removed from it) before the merge takes place.

Until the merge actually happens, all those questions and answers which had the old tag are and should be recorded under the old tag. If you want the scores to be combined, then you need to convince a moderator to perform the merge.

I've merged the two tags in this case.