# One-way tag synonym (implication)

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

Looking to this [Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

> Tag synonyms allow us to fix incorrect tags by substituting them with the correct tags.
>
> Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged with the wrong or incorrect tag -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a good idea to propose a tag synonym.

So it is clear that cases like [ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) and [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools) should be synonyms.

But what if a tag implies another tag, but in reverse this cannot be applied. example:

- [ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis) is a type of [etl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etl) tool
- [etl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etl) is not necessarily referring to [ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis)

So [ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis) tag score should alter [etl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etl) tag score (including for tag badges), but not the other way around.

Can Stack Overflow take this into consideration?

Comment: Not sure if this would be called a synonym then. But I like the idea to assume a master for each slave. Just needed to tag [laravel] with [php] in H&I.

Comment: This assumes a hierarchy in tags, which is just not something that has ever taken off. See also [Scores in parent tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316841/215552)