# What to do with a question that's been asked in order to create a tag for a new synonym?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, tag-synonym-process, tag-creation-process

I follow the [knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js) tag, and noticed [this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558510/id-like-to-introduce-new-tag-ko-and-make-it-a-synonym-for-knockout-js) that has been asked solely to create a new tag ([ko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ko)) that the OP noticed wasn't present in the system, which they'd then like to make a synonym of the existing [knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js).

I feel that this isn't the right way to go about it - as noted in one of my comments:

> perhaps it doesn't exist because when people are asking questions, they're quite happily finding and using the existing knockout.js tag? Is there any evidence to suggest that people are mistagging their knockout questions because they can't find a suitable tag?

I initially voted to close->migrate the question to meta, but then realised that would defeat the purpose of the question itself (ie to create the tag).

What to do with the question, and also more generally with the idea of creating a tag just to make it a synonym?

Comment: It is still a meta question, so I did close vote to get it migrated here. If questions need that tag there are plenty of questions it could be added to. If that is something that is needed is to be discussed by participants in that tag, which doesn't include me.

Comment: Right, so it's not required to ask a new question to create a new tag - you could just add it to an existing one.  That part at least makes sense

Comment: Please add that important piece of information in your help system. "... or just add it to an existing question.".

Answer (score 1):

This specific question has now been migrated to meta ([I'd like to introduce new tag [ko] and make it a synonym for [knockout.js]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299865)).

The more general case is covered in [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)