# Missing tags for libreoffice

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently there is no tag for libreoffice-writer but there are tags for pretty much every thing else.
I would like to propose that not only is a `libreoffice-writer` tag created but also the tag `libreoffice-python`.
This is an area that is fraught with issues concerning either the utter lack of documentation and the mess that any existing documentation is currently in. I think a `libreoffice-python` tag would help track down specific questions and answers in this area without trawling through all of the `libreoffice` questions.

Comment: Please read [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: I'll dig out some of my old questions on the subjects proposed.