# Proposing new tag: oracle-ords

Tags: support, tags

How would I go ahead and propose this?

The thing is that Oracle has split the development cycle of Oracle APEX and Apex Listener.

During the split they renamed `APEX Listener` to `Oracle Rest Data Services` ([ORDS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/overview/index.html))

You can use ORDS as a standalone REST module without the need for APEX.  But all questions about ORDS are being flagged with tag `oracle-apex` even though the question has nothing to do with APEX.

ORDS is fairly new, early access v2 came out in Mars 2015.  Current version is 3.0.1 from June 29, 2015.  But I see a huge increase in the use of ORDS.

- ORDS + Oracle NOSQL Database
- ORDS without APEX (production setups)
- ORDS standalone
- ORDS + APEX etc..

So it seems to make logical sense to create a new `oracle-ords` tag to live besides `oracle-apex`

Thank you

Olafur

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306064/how-do-i-create-a-new-stackoverflow-tag) came up yesterday as duplicate of [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: "As an alternative, you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new meta discussion. This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if the new tag is needed."  <-- I am opening the discussion.