# Should I create a [octance-sdk] tag for an SDK mentioned in a small number of questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

There's currently [4 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=octane%20sdk) regarding the OctaneSDK, a library created by Impinj for the purpose of interfacing with their RFID equipment. This isn't a lot, but I would think that it's still a valid case for a tag, as:

- The name is quite unique, and;
- There's questions specifically about it

What is the general consensus on this?

I'm now aware that there's an existing question **[When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)**, though this question doesn't address whether very small usage is an issue for tag validity.

Comment: @davidism Certainly related but I'd argue not duplicate. That answer says "if you think there is a clear need" which is very subjective, whereas my question is more trying to flesh out specifics about that. Namely is a very small usage an issue for tag creation. So different in outcome.

Comment: If this question keeps getting close votes, could someone please address where my reasoning above falls short?

Comment: That's the official FAQ.  Since you have the privilege, you're assumed trusted enough to use it at your discretion.  If you feel that it's lacking clarity, comment or edit that answer.

Comment: @davidism Ok cool, I've made a small addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help identify the questions for those who can answer them, and is not a meta tag or a synonym of an existing tag.  Go ahead and create it.

Comment: Cool, done: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/octane-sdk/info

Comment: @andrewb make sure to add a relevant wiki and excerpt.  Even a simple summary is better than nothing.

Comment: wiki added alongside excerpt