# Want a new tag : [typings]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

[typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typings): https://github.com/typings/typings is now the official way to get TypeScript definitions (previous tool tsd has been deprecated https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269)

I tried creating a tag for it but got the following error:

[image]

Would be great if someone could create it.

More about me (I love TypeScript) this is not a personal whim: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typescript/topusers

Questions about [tag:]typings:

- [Do I need to compile definition files alongside Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046950/do-i-need-to-compile-definition-files-alongside-typescript)
- [What are typescript typings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590168/what-are-typescript-typings)
- [TypeScript npm typings feature changes import semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623590/typescript-npm-typings-feature-changes-import-semantics)
- ETC : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+typings - not a true representation as we don't have a typings tag but the top few gave the others samples I've presented

## Update:

This question was closed as a duplicate of [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)

This is not a duplicate because

- I understand how tag creation works.
- I have more than enough rep to create it and *still it failed to create it*. Hence this *support* issue

Comment: What would this tag add over just using the typescript tag?

Comment: At least make it `typescript-typings`, or you'll get lots of unrelated type error questions tagged with it.

Comment: I agree with Jeffrey and disagree with closing this specific request as a duplicate of a general reference question. It looks like a useful tag, just not in the ambiguous form that you've suggested.

Comment: Nobody likes the silly tautology of [typescript][typescript-typings], nobody will ever just use [typescript-typings].  Adding the [typings] tag is fine, it is not a sensible plural of the existing [typing] tag and all top google hits talk about Typescript.

Comment: Given that Typings is a tool that is likely to have widespread adoption (given the TypeScript userbase and the key part this is going to play I think that's a fair assessment) I think that it merits a tag by itself.

Comment: I agree with Hans. `typings` seems distinct enough to me. On a related note, this new typings project looks like a step in the right direction... I had some annoyances with tsd.

Comment: Are asker being underserved by using typescript?

Comment: @HansPassant It looks like [tag:typescript-typings] has been used over 4,000 times since late 2016 (and still is used these days) (just FYI).

Answer (score 1):

This was completed back in 2016 with the creation of a tag called [typescript-typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-typings).