# Is there a case to add a visio-shapesheet tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I would like to add a visio-shapesheet tag to SO, but does the community feel this is a good candidate?

Comment: Any clues on the down vote?  How do you feel I should improve my question?

Comment: Tags don't get added by some formal process. They get added informally and unceremoniously when a user with retagging privileges adds them to an applicable question. If there are enough applicable questions to which that tag is applied, bingo bango, it becomes a tag. Certainly doesn't require a discussion on Meta. (Which may explain the downvote.)

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray.  I had read this answer (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work), which says "As an alternative, you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new meta discussion. This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if the new tag is needed."  I guess I'll have to improve my points standing.  Anyway, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Well, yeah, I guess starting a discussion on Meta is always an option for pretty much anything. But there still needs to be a *basis* for the tag's creation. By that, I mean that there should be a non-trivial number of questions that should be tagged with the new tag *right now*. With that in mind, you could make a much stronger case by linking to some of those questions in this Meta discussion. As a side benefit, Meta users with the necessary privileges could just go in and create the tag, and you (or others) could complete the retag.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out there is a shapesheet tag so I now feel a bit of an idiot.  It's only attached to 15 answers, but, it is there.  I shall mark my own answer and hopefully it will get buried where no one can see it.  I will go and propose the tag info and update the Visio wiki to make up.  Thanks again @CodyGray for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question by saying, yes, I believe there should be a visio-shapesheet tag in SO.  My reasons are:

1. When writing code against Visio you are frequently addressing cells within the ShapeSheet
2. Coded solutions normally rely on certain cells to exist within a target shape's ShapeSheet and either be read or written to.  Without these dependent cells the solution will not function.
3. Separating the ShapeSheet component of a question to SU potentially breaks up the related information.
4. The ShapeSheet does not form part of everyday product use - you have to have turned developer mode on to access it.