# Synonymise [pdf#] with [pdfsharp]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I cannot add tags yet, but I have a suggestion - could we add [pdf#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf%23) as a synonym to [pdfsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfsharp)?

Comment: The name of that library is PDFsharp, not PDF-octothorpe.

Comment: # is generally known as sharp. as in C#

Comment: Yes, and that's already an abuse. The [music sharp sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/266F/index.htm) is visibly different from the [octothorpe](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0023/index.htm). Music flat sign is also not a lowercase `b` either.

Comment: a sign/word/character can have multiple meanings, in code it means sharp, in the music "scene" its called an octothorpe, currently we are talking in a programming related meta, so the # means sharp. no need to downvote for that. Also if you are so against the # character used to define C# you should consider removing it from your profile.

Comment: I did not downvote for that. And please leave my profile alone. There is already a glyph that means "music sharp sign", there is no need to recycle another one to hijack that meaning. Also, are you sure *octothorpe* is used in the music "scene"? To me it always was programming-related (it comes from Bell Labs).

Comment: Its funny how much of a hypocrite you are, saying that is a mis-usage of a character and than using it yourself on this wrong way. Music & Telephone scene if you want to be even more specific, still its one of the lesser used characters. it could use some new live, also, do you avoid twitter because its not a "hashtag" ?

Comment: I avoid Twitter for other reasons :) Now, more seriously, appropriateness of that character aside, what would introducing such a synonym achieve in the first place? The name of the library uses plain *sharp*, neither a sharp sign nor an octothorpe, so why create a synonym that does just that? You're not providing any rationale to back up your suggestion.

Comment: I don't see the need to create that tag unless you can elaborate why the current tag isn't sufficient to find those questions http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this would be an ***utterly silly*** tag synonym. The [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) library is actually known as, well, PDFsharp. It isn't "PDF#" or "PDF♯" or any of that. It is spelled out in words, *just like the existing tag*.

Comment: My suggestion comes from the fact that it is more common to use shorthand version these days, and this could save very important miliseconds.

Comment: For pete's sake, the tag box has *autocompletion*. All you have to do is type the first three letters. If you are using a shorthand version, you are doing it wrong. That is not the name of the library.

Answer (score 2):

A [Google for PDF#](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf%23&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl#) returned exactly 0 hits for PDF# in the top pages.  As such, it's probably not a widely used abbreviation.

Conversely, a [Google for PDFSharp](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf%23&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=pdfsharp) returned plenty of hits.

It's safe to say PDFSharp is the proper usage as the name of the open source .Net library.

Comment: `A Google for PDF# returned exactly 0 hits for PDF# in the top pages. ` That's because google ignores the `#` character in search terms, so you *actually* searched for "pdf", not because nothing on the internet uses `PDF#` to refer to PDFSharp.

Comment: [Does it?](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%23)

Comment: [Yes, yes it does](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search).  Certain very common searches are special cased, such as in your example, but in the vast majority of cases, including this one, the punctuation is just ignored.