# Add jquery-lastest tag, include jQuery lastest version at stacksnippets.com

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

From *[Can I pass Promises to jQuery.when(), or only Deferreds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434557/can-i-pass-promises-to-jquery-when-or-only-deferreds)*:

> Until 3.0 is really released, you can assume jquery-tagged questions
>   not to use it (and the jQuery docs not to cover it). And even then, we
>   might need a new tag, given that they behave vastly different.

-[Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434557/can-i-pass-promises-to-jquery-when-or-only-deferreds?noredirect=1#comment60486305_36434557)

> Add `jquery-latest` tag ? Include
>   `"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"` at stacksnippets ?

-[guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434557/can-i-pass-promises-to-jquery-when-or-only-deferreds?noredirect=1#comment60488595_36434557)

---

Feature request:

1. Add `jquery-lastest` tag at Stack Overflow;
2. Add `"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"` or other official latest unstable build of jQuery to the version list at stacksnippets.com

Comment: related (if not a duplicate) for the first question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: A tag with a constantly-changing meaning? Never, all the time only the newest questions would have a chance of being tagged properly. An option for the latest unstable build of a js library in stack-snippets? Useless for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @Deduplicator See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-next . jsfiddle currently has option for `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js` , why not stacksnippets ? stacksnippets lists jQuery version 1.2.3 , why not latest build ?

Comment: @guest271314 Looks like this tag needs to die as well. What will become of it when ECMA changes version? Will you manually retag them all to the final `ecmascript-xx`?

Comment: @guest271314 So, others had that same brilliant idea already? Why am I not surprised? Do you think anyone goes through the question whenever a new ecmascript revision is proposed and retags everything which happens to be mistagged thereafter?

Comment: Not certain why Question is receiving "downvote"s ? Why allow jQuery version 1.2.3 at stacksnippets though not latest build ?

Comment: @Deduplicator According to link posted by rene , the tag can be created without asking for it at feature-request here at meta, which was unaware of , here. Though cannot fathom why jQuery 1.2.3 would be included at stacksnippets, though not latest unstable build ?

Comment: @Tunaki: [[tag:ecmascript-next]] has the very specific meaning of "feature that is proposed for a future revision of ES that is not yet known". It's at least better than tagging them with the revision that it is proposed for but will eventually not be included in - see [tag:es7]. But you're right, in general we should avoid such tags like the plague.

Comment: @guest271314: Don't forget that [voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: The problem with having a StackSnippet pointing to the latest unstable build is that in 2 years time, it won't be anymore. But you'll still point to the latest unstable build, which will probably completely break your answer. This is why sticking to fixed version is better: stability over time guaranteed.

Comment: @Tunaki: Can you put that comment in an answer, please?

Comment: @Tunaki The build date of the version used at the snippet could be appended to stacksnippets ui panel, for comparison purposes. The latest build can currently be included using `external library` link. If version 1.2.3 is available at list, why not latest ?

Comment: @guest271314: Because it's no more relevant for the question it was posted to. That's how comments work.

Comment: @Bergi Ok. Was not certain if you had rescinded your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Add [jquery-lastest] tag at stackoverflow

As pointed out in the comments, such a tag doesn't make sense. Its meaning would change with every revision of jQuery.

However, I've went ahead and tagged the few questions (5!) we have about jQuery 3.0 with the new tag [jquery-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-3).

> Add latest unstable build of jQuery to version list at stacksnippets

I don't see a good reason for that. We should wait for the official release.

Until then, you still can add it manually to your stack snippet. And even with that, you still have the problem that the script changes its content which might invalidate your question/answer, so you should always link a very specific build and not just `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js`.

Comment: _"so you should always link a very specific build"_ What would be the argument against adding `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-beta1.js` http://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/14/jquery-3-0-beta-released/ to stacksnippets ?

Comment: That it's only a beta release and not supposed to be used in production? That it's not used very often yet? No idea, actually I don't care whether it would be added or not.

Comment: Hey @Bergi, I blinked a few times and adjusted my glasses when I saw a tag with the name [tag:query-3] instead of [tag:jquery-3], but it looks like it was just a typo in your answer :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Thanks, fixed. Glad I made the typo here and not in one of the question :-)

Comment: Yet another freaking pointless tag created, thank you...

Comment: @Braiam: I'm pretty sure it will become more relevant in the future, and I felt we already had (barely) enough questions to start it. Meets [the rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/1048572) imo. If you disagree, please elaborate on "*freaking pointless*" - and it surely isn't too late to wipe it again.

Comment: @Bergi [the pointlessness illustrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-3), 31 questions asked with the tag, 29 with jquery. If you don't add jquery [your question gets ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-3%20not%20jquery?mode=all)

Comment: @Braiam I don't think tags exist only to attract viewers, but also to make topics easier to find. Of course, every [tag:es6] question also gets tagged with [tag:javascript] - and every [tag:jquery-3] question with [tag:jquery].

Comment: @Bergi tags exist with the sole purpose to bring questions to the ones who are able to answer. This tag doesn't meet this purpose.

Comment: @Braiam Tags also help with finding relevant questions via the search - which is at least as important to select answerable questions to users. And yes, you *can* be an expert for problems with migrating to jQuery 3, so I think the tag is totally valid.

Comment: @Bergi "also"? That's *not* important. I can search perfectly fine using "jquery 3" in google and it will bring **more relevant results**. Read the help center for creating tags: You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that **your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site**. jQuery-3 isn't a "new topic", is the same good old jquery topic.