# Is there another way to get a tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support

I have am a contributor on an open source project called VOLTTRON. I would like to be able to have users tag questions with that name. Is there a way to do this without having 1500 reputation points on Stack Overflow?

For clarification our project is located at https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there existing questions that could be tagged with it? If so, can you link to some of them?

Comment: We are just starting to do this.  Since we are a python group we are going to start having people post questions to that tag and then go from there.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/578411

Comment: If questions are general Python questions then that tag makes sense. However, if the question is about developing/using the VOLTTRON platform then that is more specific and could be covered by the new tag.  A question about the usage of the VOLTTRON platform would probably not be something a python enthusiast would be able to answer as it is not part of the python core.

Comment: If you're just getting started, it'd probably best to wait until someone actually asks a question in regards to VOLTTRON as opposed to trying to astroturf questions about it.

Comment: VOLTTRON itself has been around for several years however we haven't even thought about having a Stack Overflow presence until recently.

Comment: After reading the reply about tags etc.  I think that this is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: How long your software has been around does not ultimately matter when it comes to using SO. Whenever I've run into cases of people who were seeding questions to SO, I've flagged for moderator attention, and the questions were gone. Letting users ask their questions as they come up is really the way to go.

Comment: Totally agree that is the way to go.  As time goes by we assume that as we advertise that this is how we would like to answer questions I am confident that eventually we will have enough fodder to have a new tag.  Our first question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085315/install-python-packages-in-volttron/38085531#38085531 woot on our way :)

Comment: @Fuzz I added (and created) the tag on that question. Now it's your turn to improve the wiki :). Refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one.