# Create a new tag for [qlalr]

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process

QLALR is a parser generator designed for and shiped with the Qt framework.

Because there is almost no documentation for that tool I would like to add some to "Stackoverflow Documentation". This is currently not possible because I cannot even propose that tag since it is not available.

The description text could be something like:
"QLALR is a parser generator designed for and shiped with the Qt framework. It generates LALR parsers and is also used in the Qt framework to generate the parser for QtScript and QXmlStream."

I found the following question that would benefit from a `qlalr` tag:

[QLALR - QParser example crashes at startup on Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839606/qlalr-qparser-example-crashes-at-startup-on-visual-studio-2008)

And this one asked by me, which does not directly address QLALR but the `bison` tag could be replaced with `qlalr`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118092/how-to-write-a-parser-generator-for-that-task

Comment: Are there any existing questions that could benefit from having the tag? That's a prerequisite.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/6304349)

Comment: @Stijin Yes there are few.

Comment: If there are questions that could benefit from the tag just link them here and someone with sufficient reputation can create the tag for you.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the FAQ entry I linked to?

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1) Ask a question about QLALR and tag it with [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt).
- Step 2) Leave a comment on the question, asking users with 1500 or more rep to tag it with [qlalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qlalr).
- Step 3) IIRC, anyone should be able to create a documentation proposal for [qlalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qlalr) once it hits 500 questions.

Comment: Isn't asking a question, just to ask for a tag, the wrong way?

Comment: @exilit Why not ask a question **that involves a real-life problem** as an excuse for creating the tag? Even better, you can post a self-answered question.

Comment: Because that would require me to wait for a real-life problem before I can write documentation.

Comment: @exilit if nobody has any problems why do we need documentation?

Comment: @RobertLongson Are you serios? Sure somebody has problems, but not everything is asked on StackOverflow. In fact I recently had problems (many of them I already solved myself without asking) and still have some.  But because I already made mistakes and learned something about the way to use I would like to share my knowledge. Isn't this the whole point of (StackOverflow) documentation?

Comment: The point is that documentation needs to document common things, not obscure ones.

Comment: @RobertLongson And exactly this is what I want to do. I wanted to perform quite common tasks with QLALR (i.e. creating a parser). QLALR is a useful tool but because of missing documentation it is much harder to get the job done than it should be (which maybe prevents people from using it). You not only need documentation if somebody has problems, it is exactly the other way around: You write documentation to prevent problems!