# Create a tag for output validation?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

The [`validation`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/validation/info) tag seems to only apply to **input** validation:

> Data validation is the process of ensuring that a program operates on
>   clean, correct and useful data.

One of its synonyms is `input-validation`.

Should there be an analogous new `output-validation` tag?

Or should `validation`'s description also include mention of output (and a `output-validation` synonym?

Comment: Are there any questions that would benefit from that tag? See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Search

"output validation"
returns 
53 results

Answer (score 5):

No, that tag shouldn’t be created.

[validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) by itself has over 40K questions. Your own research shows there are 53 questions that could have the tag [output-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/output-validation). I doubt the knowledge needed for validation, either being on the input or output side of a process/function/method is that much different. That [input-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input-validation) is already a synonym is a signal that it didn’t need to be separated.

If anything needs to be done it is with [validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) itself. Are followers able to find their questions and answers within those 44K of posts, are there enough related tags that help the community to find the posts they are looking for?

Adding a tag to find 53 questions is not one of the actions I think would be helpful here.