# Create a new tag l10ns

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm the author of L10ns http://l10ns.org/ It's a tool for handlings internationalization for JavaScript applications. I'm wondering if you could create a tag `l10ns`, to tag specific questions to my tool? Since other competing/relevant tools in the i18n space got their own tags. I think L10ns is eligible.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 7):

That's... not how it works.

If someone comes along and wants to ask a question about your tool, awesome. *At that point*, they create the [l10ns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/l10ns) tag.

If nobody comes along wanting to ask a question about your tool, then there's no need to have a tag here for it - it would just get automatically deleted, anyway.

*(Side note: you've got enough rep to do this yourself - tags can be created by anyone with 1500 rep)*

Comment: I wanted to create the tag. Though it notified me to post a question in meta to add the tag!

Comment: It is because the name is similar to the `l10n` tag. And it remaps to `localization` tag. If `l10ns` is a new tag. Then I should raise it in meta which I just did.

Comment: @einstein if you add those comments in your question and include a couple of questions where you think the tag could be added and your concern about the exact naming of the tag, I'll re-open the question. Let me know once you have done that.