# Why do Stack Exchange websites block me from using my preferred tags when asking questions

Tags: discussion, tags

What advantage comes from forcing new users to use tags that they believe won't represent their question as well as their original choice? For example, just now I asked a question about analogue computers and fuzzy and boolean logic, and wasn't allowed to use [analogue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/analogue), [fuzzy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fuzzy), [boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boolean) or pretty much any other useful tag, so had settle for [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logic).

Comment: What tag are you trying to use that you can't?

Comment: But you do select a tag that already exists, right? Because you can't yet create tags on your own. An other option: It might be that a tag is a synonym and then it switches to the *master* tag.

Comment: Based on your latest edit, can you also take some time to answer the above comments? Because the lack of that information is causing the down votes ...

Comment: Those seem like *awful* tags on their own. Remember, the point of tags is to categorize information in a way that makes it retrievable and when the system keeps you from using a tag, there's been a lot of thought that went into the decision. That doesn't mean every decision made here is always correct, but there's more to it. Fuzzy logic has `fuzzy-logic` and that's what would make most sense to use, no?  Can't comment on analogue computers

Comment: [Fuzzy](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fuzzy/info) says *do not use* in the excerpt, The tag analogue does not exist, so you can't use that tag, it has to be created first but I doubt anyone would be willing to do so. boolean can be used but that tag is very broad...

Comment: You're confusing sites. Your question is on cs.stackexchange.com, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Its all the same format. I use Stack Overflow most and have had the same issue there. Im still yet to get an actual answer as to users with low reputation cant use tags of choice.

Comment: `Im still yet to get an actual answer as to users with low reputation cant use tags of choice` because the point of tags is to create *a useful system of categorizing information,* and allowing any tag runs counter to that goal. Tags aren't there for *you* - they are for the rest of the world to find your question.

Comment: creating tags is a privilege: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags that comes at 1500 rep. Also related: [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Creating tags is a rep privilege but higher-rep users can't create tags willy nilly, either. Bad tags get frequently taken out of circulation no matter who created them.

Comment: Not allowed to use "boolean" or anything related. "Fuzzy-logic" I'll give you. Wasnt aware that such specific double barrels were available.

Comment: "Boolean" on Stack Overflow would not be likely to work - anyone and their dog with a problem in code that happens to contain a boolean variable would use it, rendering it useless. But even with impeccable use it seems hard to see how it's a useful categorization - are there any scenarios where looking for, say, C++ questions involving "boolean" make sense?  Maybe  it's different on a CS site.

Comment: "boolean" seems to be possible to use as a tag??

Answer (score 8):

Most of the tags that you think you'd want to add have since been removed (or blacklisted) and replaced with more specific and more focused tags, which one should look to use instead.

Don't resort to [meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) in this scenario; you want your tagging to be as specific as it possibly can to be sure that the best people possible can see your question.  Just take a moment with your questions to think about if the tag you want to use can be interpreted as a bit inspecific, since "fuzzy" is inspecific (fuzzy time, fuzzy math, fuzzy logic, fuzzy data).

Comment: Not sure, that question if from 2014. I _think_ they're talking about [that one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64971/how-do-analogue-computers-perform-logical-operations)

Comment: @Tunaki:  Perhaps, but a) they're on the wrong Meta, and b) if I remove the specific question focus, I don't see how the answer isn't valuable advice.

Comment: Didn't say it wasn't valuable advice. Was just commenting on the specific question. It could be that they don't know that there are different Metas.

Comment: You're absolutely right on that @Tunaki; I was more reacting to me needing to remove the specific question reference.