# Help creating tags for Bare Metal Cloud SDKs

Tags: discussion, tags

I own developer experience for Oracle's [Bare Metal Cloud Services](https://cloud.oracle.com/en_US/bare-metal). We'd like to direct users who are familiar with Stack Overflow to ask questions about our SDKs and CLI on Stack Overflow, but right now we have no way to be notified of new questions related to us, because there are no tags related to our services for customers to use in their posts, and for us to subscribe to to more quickly hear about questions we should answer.

Based on reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work):

> As an alternative, you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new meta discussion. This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if the new tag is needed.

I was hoping someone with enough reputation could create some tags for my team:

- oracle-bmcs-java-sdk (Java SDK for Oracle Bare Metal Cloud Services)
- oracle-bmcs-ruby-sdk (Ruby SDK for Oracle Bare Metal Cloud Services)
- oracle-bmcs-python-sdk (Python SDK for Oracle Bare Metal Cloud Services)
- oracle-bmcs-hdfs-connector (HDFS Connector for Oracle Bare Metal Cloud Services)
- oracle-bmcs-cli (CLI for Oracle Bare Metal Cloud Services)
- oracle-bmcs (Oracle Bare Metal Cloud Services combines the elasticity and utility of public cloud with the granular control, security, and predictability of on-premises infrastructure to deliver high-performance, high availability and cost-effective infrastructure services)

I appreciate your help here.

Comment: Related meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project

Comment: Not that I know of (we very recently released the SDKs, and getting tags set up on StackOverflow is part of our support-readiness plan) but since specific tags don't exist yet, we don't have a good way of knowing for sure. A general search for "oracle bare metal" did not return anything.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick response, and consideration. If I were to post questions that we have gotten via other channels, and answer them, would that work?

Comment: Happy to wait, I need to round up the Q&As I'd want to post that would cover all these tags anyway :)

Comment: For downvoters - unless you post a comment, its not constructive. I can't learn from a downvote with no reason given. I am following the guidance mentioned here in the accepted answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work. If that guidance is not correct, it should be updated.

Comment: @Joe: "*For downvoters - unless you post a comment, its not constructive.*" Nonsense. On MSO, downvotes mean disagreement.

Comment: I'm aware downvotes mean disagreement. But disagreement with what? The tag names? The desire to create tags before a question related to them? The guidance in an existing accepted answer with 37 upvotes?

Comment: The downvote button has an informational tooltip which I believe may apply here, "does not show any research effort". There is a [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) specifically about how to get support on Stack Overflow for a product.

Comment: I did research - as my post says, I followed guidance based on the accepted answer on the MSO [wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work) around this topic. I also just read the help article you suggested -- it says to monitor the tags. That's exactly what I'd like to do, and why I'm asking for help with tag creation. This product is brand new, and I'm trying to make sure we can easily monitor any questions that get posted, before any real customer questions get posted that we might miss because tags don't exist.

Comment: What does "own developer experience" mean?

Comment: The most obvious possible reason for the downvotes on this question would be disagreement with the suggestion that those tags should be created.

Comment: By developer experience, I meant the SDKs, CLI, and REST APIs for our various services. @Pekka, thanks for the feedback. In terms of not wanting those tags to be created -- AWS, Azure, and Google Cloud all have tags on StackOverflow for their services and SDKs.

Comment: I don't know how to say this tactfully, so I'll say it bluntly: I downvoted because you sound like a manager trying to promote your company's project.  When companies refer people to Stack Overflow, as opposed to people organically coming to SO on their own, [it hasn't gone very well for anyone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=reach+out+to+is%3Aq): users get their questions closed (and get angry at what they view as the company not helping them) and SO users have to clean up after them. Also, fairly or not, being associated with Oracle makes me suspicious of your motives.

Comment: @Jeffrey, appreciate the honesty and your articulating the reason for downvoting. Not that it should matter, but I'm not a manager, I [write code](http://jodoglevy.com/jobloglevy/) and use SO a lot. I have no interest in promoting this project to SO users, I have an interest in making sure users of this project are able to easily use outlets they're already comfortable with to ask (appropriate) questions to my team. We are planning to mention SO as one of a few options where users can reach out for help, and I expect only users already familiar with SO to choose that option over the others.

Answer (score 1):

Tags needs for questions on the site, not backwards. I think that instead, you will have to either, wait for someone to have an organic question about those topics (I believe that they either will reuse a per-existent tag or would create it), or ask yourself a *good question* to use the tag.

Remember, tags are for users to look for questions they are able to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If I wait for someone to ask an organic question, how would I find that question when there's no related tag for me to subscribe to? Am I expected to search every day on StackOverflow for terms I think they might use? Sure, if I post my own question, I will make sure its relevant to the StackOverflow community.