# Create an [ideascript] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

**Overview**

I do not yet have a high enough reputation to create a tag, but I have been working with a programming language called IDEAScript and would like to ask some questions about it. IDEAScript is the language used to create macros for the IDEA software from CasewareAnalytics.

The only documentation I have been able to find up to this point come from [this](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118004485.html) ebook and [this](http://www.ideascripting.com/) website.  Adding the ideascript tag would provide a well organized way to begin building a knowledge base around the IDEAScript language.

**Wiki excerpt**

A tag for questions related to CaseWare Analytics' IDEAScript programming language. This tag should only be used for questions about writing the macros in IDEAScript and should not be used for general questions about the IDEA software.

**Related Questions**

[How do I compare two files in IDEAScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879900/how-do-i-compare-two-files-in-ideascript)

Comment: @rene Can you explain to me what I'm missing here?  My understanding from the question you referred me to is that opening a new meta issue with the discussion tag to request a tag is an acceptable practice.  The tag I am requesting is different from the one in the referenced issue.

Comment: @rene - Are my edits sufficient for this or do I need more information?

Comment: I elaborated a bit in the [duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work) and I can't make the call based on what you have now but I'm happy to re-open it and see what others have to say/add.

Comment: @Stijn - yes, I forgot to do so.  It has now been deleted.

Comment: It seems to be a scripting language similar to VBA, so an [tag:ideascript] tag looks OK to me. /cc @rene

Comment: Be my guest @Stijn, that can give you a badge ;)

Comment: @rene Can't say I've ever come across this but seems to be similar if not VBA under the covers, but the fact it has its [own book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=47jW6OE5A5cC&lpg=PA10&ots=KoxgY778oA&dq=ideascript&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=ideascript&f=false) suggests it must have some following.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tag has been created. Feel free to make suggested edits for the tag excerpt and tag wiki, you can do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ideascript/info). The excerpt in your question looks fine.