# Creation of a tag for the Esendex API

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation-process

I see that there are some questions about the API from Esendex and that a tag could regroup them (`esendex-api`). [Here is an up-to-date list of the questions related to it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=esendex%20is%3Aquestion) (10 when writting this line).

I don't know if this is enough to ask for its creation and just wanted to ask.

The tag could help regroup theses questions that are all related to the Esendex API which is used extensively in some countries, especially in EU (as far as I know). It would make easier to find question related to it, but I don't know if 10 questions is enough to justify one and didn't find a best practice regarding the "recommended amount of questions required".

Excerpt example :

> The API of Esendex, a service to send and receive SMS

Thank you in advance and please accept my apologies if this tag is not relevant, its my first post on meta.

Comment: You got it essentially right. Here's the FAQ for tag creation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/215552