# Create a [dkan] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

### What is DKAN?

[DKAN](http://getdkan.com/) is a Drupal based open source project that makes it easier to publish Open Data. It is a complimentary offering to [CKAN](https://ckan.org/) (another open source Open Data project that currently has a [SO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ckan)) in the effort to make data more open and accessible. There's also the major difference that DKAN is built on PHP, where as CKAN is built on Python.

### Community

A [quick search of "DKAN"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dkan) on SO returns quite a few questions about the platform, and there is also a thriving community within the [DKAN GitHub](https://github.com/NuCivic/dkan), in the [mailing lists](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dkan-dev), and on the [Slack channels](https://dkan.slack.com).

### Tag

We currently have a member within our community that has the "Create Tag" privileges but doesn't want to ask a question for the sake of creating a tag (pretty sure that's against community guidelines). Unfortunately we don't have a member who can edit questions and enter tags.

### TLDR;

Please can someone make a [dkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dkan) tag on Stack Overflow?

---

Thanks to @Oded for pointing me towards [this tags creation post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)

#### Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate

- [DKAN API CSRF Validation
  Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592434/dkan-api-csrf-validation-failed?s=1%7C2.8158)
- [Dkan Drupal Error after installing field permission
  module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134273/dkan-drupal-error-after-installing-field-permission-module?s=2%7C2.1624)
- [Drush site-install dkan fails - “All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be
  NOT
  NULL”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529404/drush-site-install-dkan-fails-all-parts-of-a-primary-key-must-be-not-null?s=3%7C1.9013)

#### Explain how the tag helps in categorising and finding those questions

The DKAN tag would be an easy way to differentiate from [ckan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ckan), as well as allowing the developers and community members of DKAN to quickly find questions and identify *sore spots* within the DKAN platform. Currently a few of the questions asked about DKAN are tagged with [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal). Adding the [dkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dkan) tag would likely remove the need to use the [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal) tag so much.

#### Provide an initial tag excerpt and wiki for the new tag

> DKAN is a Drupal based open source project that makes it easier to publish Open Data.

#### Propose a good fitting name for the tag

[dkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dkan)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work - you should probably read that.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Oded, I've edited my request to fit.

Comment: Is it not possible to create new tags with suggested edits?

Comment: I was told that a user needs 2000 reputation to edit questions. Our community member only has a lowly 1500. :)

Comment: Unfortunately the last DKAN related question was my own, and I'm not able to add a new tag to it. The previous question was posted back in October and was already edited by another member of the SO community, and so it doesn't seem relevant to queue edits for a 7 month old question. However if it's entirely within community guidelines to do so then I will propose a new edit.

Comment: @RobertLongson: creating a new tag requires [1500 points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) however, wether or not you have the suggested edit privilege.

Comment: @mohnjatthews Users below 2000 reputation can still do edits, but the edits enter a review queue first and need to be approved by 3 users. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: This plopped up in the suggested edit review just now. It lacks the tag usage guidance that was proposed in this post, so I'll have to reject it for now. Please add the tag usage guidance to the tag wiki.

Comment: Your suggested initial tag excerpt is not appropriate. A tag wiki excerpt *must* provide usage guidance, like "_Use this tag for..._".

Comment: @Cœur understood, sorry about that. I was using the [ckan tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ckan/info) as a _template_.

Comment: @mohnjatthews that is also wrong as the tag excerpt is for guidance on how to use the tag, not what the tag is describing. Both need to be changed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After reading the DKAN page, your request seems fair to me.
I've created[dkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dkan), and added the tag to the 3 questions you linked.

*Note 1:* [dkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dkan) does not have any tag description / tag wiki. Feel free to edit it (or to ask for an edit) to improve it.

*Note 2:* If you find older questions related to [dkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dkan), you can edit them to add [dkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dkan). Here is [the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738400/how-to-add-dataset-in-drupal-using-api) I've found.