# How to add a nonexistent tag synonym

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I was at a talk yesterday where the speaker said: "Use the [h2o] tag on Stack Overflow. Be careful, we've had people use h20 (h-two-zero) by mistake and not find anything."

So, I thought I'd add "h20" as a synonym. But I get:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a
>   synonym!

I.e. people are (apparently) searching on it, but no-one has used it on a question (yet). Adding [h20] on a question, just so I can add it as a synonym, feels so wrong...

Comment: water we supposed to do? More seriously, I think its like that under the assumption that if the (nonexistant) tag hasn't been used incorrectly yet, then it doesn't need a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the tag [h20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/h20) doesn't exist, you can't create it as a synonym.

[Tag creation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work) isn't done lightheartedly. There needs to be questions that would benefit from the tag in the first place. Tags can only be created when they are added to a question. There is no *add a tag* functionality outside of a question.

Once the tag exists it can be used for a synonym.