# Create a tag [json-p] for Java EE specification of the JSON Processing API

Tags: support, tags, tag-disambiguation, tag-creation-request

I tried to create the new tag [json-p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-p) but SO prevents this because of an existing [jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonp) tag that is about something else:

> You are attempting to create the tag [json-p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-p); however the tag [jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonp) already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.

As the [Java API for JSON Processing (JSR-353)](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/) is an important part of the Java EE specification and "JSON-P" seems to be the official short form I would like to propose this new tag.

The added value consists of the ability to distinguish questions about non-standardized, library-specific or language-agnostic [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) topics from questions about the standardized JSON-P API.

Comment: Is there anyone going to not be able to answer these questions if it doesn't has the tag? Doesn't another tag covers this topic?

Comment: @Braiam Questions can be answered completely without tags. Tags are there not only to help this single guy asking a question, but also to assist the thousand other visitors later. Tags also attract experts on a certain technology which can follow tags and provide answers faster. There is also no other tag covering the topic.

Comment: You seem to not able to see my point, so let me rephrase: are there experts not being able to answer these questions if the tag doesn't exist? Is there any expert willing to follow and answer questions with this tag, even if it doesn't have any other tag? Is there any need for the tag?

Comment: Let's see, whether this question gains some interest over time. :-)

Comment: @Jens tags that differ only so much are just going to end up causing confusion and wrongly tagged questions. Could something more explicit like json-processing-api work?

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, this sounds like a reasonable alternative.

Comment: @Jens if you also suggest a tag wiki for it saying something along the line it's known as JSON-P etc... That'd be great.

Comment: Has this been addressed by the creation of any tag in the intervening 5 years since the request was made? If so, please post an answer stating which tag was chosen, so we can update this and mark it as completed. If not, please [edit] this question to include links to some questions on the main site that should have the tag (see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944).

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for coming back to this topic. The whole discussion boils down to the issue of consistent handling of tag homonyms, which I think still needs improvement on SE. It looks like there now exist more specific tags: [tag:jsr-353] and [tag:jsr-374], but [tag:jsonp] is confused in several cases. Actually [tag:jsonp] should be renamed to json-with-padding and for the Java API there could be a new tag json-processing-api or json-processing-java-api. Both should be suggested, when someone tries to apply jsonp.