# Please help me create a "extentreports" tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

**About ExtentReports**

ExtentReports is an open-source reporting API for Java and .NET.  It creates interactive HTML report of your test session.

**The Problem**

Approximately 200 questions exist on stackoverflow pertaining to ExtentReports, however, they have not been tagged correctly.  Some users have tagged these questions as "extent" whereas many have not tagged their questions at all.

**How the tag helps**

If there was an "extentreports" tag, it will help the developers and the users quickly filter through all questions; provide better support for users using this forum to seek help.

Comment: Some of them are already tagged [extent]. That tag has 75 questions in it, a number of which are actually extent-reports. The rest appear to be something related to r-lang rasters.

Comment: New tags can be created when asking a question only for normal users (moderators may also be able to just create them). What you could already do, is write up a tag wiki (long description) and a short description.That way it will take a lot less effort of a moderator to create a good tag. You can edit your question with the proposed descriptions. [tag:extent] is a vague tag in my opinion (it's ambiguous) and might be a candidate for burnination.

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one) for how to write a good tag wiki, and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work) for when a new tag is appropriate. I think this tag qualifies.

Comment: Correction: normal users (if high rep enough) seem to be able to create tags by editing existing questions, and since there are already lots of questions that should be untagged with [tag:extent] and tagged with this tag, I think we can do it. If you've written up a tag wiki, and no-one here has a solid argument for me not to create this tag, I will create it. That way the moderators can just keep on doing the good work without having to spend time on this.

Comment: Thank you Erik..  if the tag is created, I can work on tagging all questions correctly.  I will create a tag-wiki tonight.

Comment: @Anshoo Still haven't heard from you with the tag wiki. You can copy-paste it in your question (as proposed tag wiki). Make sure to comment to notify me with the @ symbol, so I get notified when you're finished

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  
My apologies for the delay. I have updated this post with information about the API and added relevant information in case someone wonders what the tag is about. :) Thank you.

Comment: @Anshoo the [tag:extentreports] tag is created. I've added the excerpt and description, they're in the review queue. Please retag questions with this tag to make sure the tag persists