# Create the [exonum] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

There is a platform for creating permissioned blockchains called [Exonum](https://exonum.com).

Would it possible to create a tag for it? Developers, in their FAQ, indicated that they are open to help out on Stack Overflow, but without the appropriate tag it might be difficult to draw their attention.

The framework is very young, but it starts to [collect some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exonum).

Answer (score 6):

A tag cannot be created until there are questions that merit that tag.

Ideally, those questions would be on-topic for the site. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170205/exonum-as-a-framework) isn't, so it's not a very good pick.

If you can find a list of additional, *on-topic* questions that should be tagged [exonum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exonum), then I or someone else can create the tag. If not, then the tag doesn't need to exist at all.

#### See Also: [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)