# New tag request: [Twine]

Tags: feature-request, tags

[Twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine) is reccommended by [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) for the uploading of Python packages. It is more secure than

```
python setup.py upload
```

for older versions of Python

[Current questions matching "Twine" and "Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=twine%20python)

Existing questions which would benefit from this tag:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908822/python-import-error-when-using-twine-and-anaconda)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266321/python-pypi-upload-error-with-twine)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168284/is-there-still-an-advantage-using-twine-for-python-pkg-upload)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420713/import-error-when-using-twine-and-wheel-to-upload-python-package-to-pypi)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445760/twine-wont-let-me-register-or-upload-my-package-is-https-upload-pypi-org-leg)
[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970887/python-ssl-certificate-validation-fails-on-some-distribution-commands)
[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764909/twine-can-not-upload-to-pypi-org)
[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961730/400-error-invalid-uri-when-uploading-new-pypi-package-twine)
[9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018965/error-when-uploading-to-pypi-valueerror-no-pkg-info-in-archive)
[10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184892/what-does-twine-upload-dist-command-do)
(There are plenty more in the above results too)

Tag summary:

> Twine is a Python package used for uploading distributions to the
> Python Package Index (PyPI).

Excerpt:

> Twine is a utility for securely interacting with [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) over HTTPS. PyPi is the Python Package Index - a repository of software for the Python programming language.
>
> Twine is one of two ways to upload to PyPi, the other being through the "setup.py upload" command.

Comment: Seems very appropriate, odd that it doesn't exist yet.  They are downvoting your proposal, hopefully somebody will post a comment to explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: Can you provide a (non-plagiarized / not copy-pasted) tag excerpt and tag wiki for that tag that explains which questions can be asked with that tag. That would be helpful if creation is considered.

Comment: @rene - I've edited to include a summary and excerpt now

Comment: @ECH I should have linked you to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one). Your texts read as marketing speak where they should explain when the tag should be used. Sorry about that but you'll have to revisit that.

Comment: Please do read the [FAQ on tag creation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work) and address the topics listed there, such as giving us some examples of existing questions and explain how the tag helps experts find those.

Comment: I first assumed the proposed tag would be for the ["open-source tool for telling interactive, nonlinear stories"](https://twinery.org/). There [don't seem to be many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=twine+story) for that at the moment, however.

Comment: There have been a grand total of 4 questions, the first one being asked in 2014. None of these questions have received many votes. There's simply not enough traffic on this topic to warrant the creation of a new tag.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that doesn't matter. If questions asked with that tag is on topic, then traffic doesn't matter here. There are hundreds of such tags exist on SO

Comment: @COLDSPEED I'm assuming you're referring to the tag which Jon Ericson suggested when you say there's only 4 questions? It's a little confusing that you're talking about that on this question - I originally thought you meant the tag I suggested, so I added some direct links to the description.

Comment: @rene I've modified the excerpt now too to sound less like marketing-speak

Comment: I've added / approved edits to add the new tag to those ten questions that you linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added the tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908822/python-import-error-when-using-twine-and-anaconda) and brought most of the [suggested tag excerpt and wiki over](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/twine/info)

Make sure users understand when and when not to use that tag. Prevent that the tag gets used incorrectly.

If you start out adding tags to existing question make sure you **do not** only suggest tag edits. Instead you should fix everything in a post or leave re-tagging to users with full edit privilege (> 2K). If you decide to edit anyway, add an extensive edit comment so reviewers understand what you're up to. And don't do it in bulk, just spread out the edits.

Have fun with your new shiny tag.

Comment: *"When tagging with PyPi consider tagging with python as well."* - Do you mean "When tagging with Twine consider ..."? You also switch between "PyPI" and "PyPi" (lowercase 'i') in the tag wiki. Are both correct?

Comment: That needed a proofreader @Tom thanks for being one. Now fixed.

Comment: It should be PyPI. I had lowercase in my question originally, so it's probably my fault! I've edited the wiki now to correct the casing.

Comment: @rene You're welcome.

Comment: @ECH You need to redo your edit suggestion, because you and rene both edited the wiki at the same time, but your edit got rejected due to that conflict.

Comment: let me edit it, i have full pivileges there, now fixed for real

Comment: ECH did that too and it got rejected again. That's really unlucky timing :D. But all is fixed :).

Comment: Unfortunate timing for me, as long as it's fixed now!