# How can I tell if my tags have been used?

Tags: support, tags

I've created a few tags ever since I've received enough reputation. How can I tell if someone else has used a tag I created? Do I get notified or is there no way of knowing?

(Are there any badges associated with creating tags?)

Comment: Click on the tags button on the top bar and find your tag. Tags that are not used are deleted.

Comment: There are no notifications, since the tag isn't technically "yours". Tags don't have owners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no notification *per se* when a tag that you created gets used. As Cerbrus says, tags are *community* resources and aren't owned by any particular user.

However, there *is* a [Taxonomist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), which is awarded to you after a tag that you have created is used by 50 questions. When you earn a badge, you do get a notification in the "Achievements" drop-down menu (the icon that looks like a trophy and lights up green). You do not have a Taxonomist badge, so no tag that you've created has gotten to 50 questions yet.

If you know which tag you want to check, you can always click on it to visit the tag page. For example, [HABJAN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561286/habjan) just earned the Taxonomist badge for creating the [ghostscript.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghostscript.net) tag. If you go to that tag page, and click on [about](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ghostscript.net/info), you'll see on the right-hand side that it was created 3 years, 8 months ago by HABJAN (took quite a while, didn't it!). You also see [the top users in that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ghostscript.net/topusers) and additional information about that tag. Anyway, that'll give you an idea of how useful a tag that you know you created has been.

Finally, it's worth referring you to [the FAQ on when tag creation is appropriate and how it works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work), and to point out that tags which are *not* used by questions are automatically removed by the system. (For example, if you created a tag by adding it to a question, but someone later decided that wasn't a good tag and removed it.)