# What to do about tag that appears to be nothing more than astroturfing?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

Tag in question: [faveod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faveod).

It has one question with one answer, both by the same user.

The entire content of the [tag's wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/faveod/info) is contributed by this same user and mostly consists of copypasta of the marketing-speak on the [product's own site](https://faveod.com/index). The English on that site is also a little suspect.

The [most recent suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17700625) to this tag's page is, again, by the same user.

Is something fishy here or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: *"The English on that site is also a little suspect."* Um.....so? What are we meant to infer from that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder some malicious behavior is prone to bad English (think phishing emails). Certainly not condemning on it's own, but a little helpful if the behavior is potentially suspect.

Comment: @LordFarquaad: And the **vastly overwhelming** incidence of bad English is just bad English by normal people. I can't begin to sign up to factoring in someone's facility with English as any part of determining malicious intent. Not remotely.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree most bad English is just normal people speaking bad English, but there's definitely a correlation between bad English and malicious intent. It's not perfect, and it doesn't imply causation, but it's there, so I think mentioning it is ok. Back to phising; if I got an email that I was skeptical of AND it had bad English, I'd me more likely to assume I shouldn't trust it. Maybe that example isn't very good though, since I typically only expect emails from fluent English-speakers, while anyone can ask questions here.

Comment: In this specific case the mistakes are typical of French web pages. Just about every non-English language has their own take on English, making a pattern of mistakes that typifies their origin.

Comment: @LordFarquaad: confidence scams (your typical phishing email looking to get some money out of Joe Soap on the street) **deliberately** use bad spelling and other small hints to weed out the wary. It is way more efficient to focus on those people that are not on the ball enough to even spot a badly worded fake email; if you make such phishing emails too perfect you have to scale your handling side up for no extra gain as you only get more people that'll spot the scam later on. So yes, there is a causation.

Comment: Came here to get involved in the community, instead learnt how to efficiently scam people

Comment: It's sad that "normal people" here apparently means "Native English speakers".  More so that it refers to those who can't even use their own native language correctly.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Makes sense. Unlike spear phishing, generic phishing email has close to zero cost but the time required to vet responses does. Sad. Another example of how the vulnerable get taken advantage of. Some things never change. Human condition.

Comment: @mickeyf I think you misunderstood the comments. The usage of "normal people" here meant non-scammers who may be native or non-native  English speakers.

Comment: I *don't* think it is deliberate. They just can't be bothered to make it correct (for whatever reason). E.g., the low quality may work well enough for them. Or it may be incentives weighing short-term gains (e.g., time) over long-term gains (much higher conversion rates).

Comment: Now (probably) a new round in the [TDEngine tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdengine). That isn't subtle (spread out over many users): Only a few users with 10 or more consecutive questions.

Comment: OK, it is this one: *[Extraordinary burnination: turn off the \[tdengine\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429255/extraordinary-burnination-turn-off-the-tdengine)*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't see anything specifically suspect here; the author doesn't appear to have a direct affiliation with the company. Creating a tag wiki from marketing material copy-pasta is unfortunately all too common. I've removed the tag again, it [doesn't meet our criteria for tag creation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944).

In future, please flag such a post for moderator attention. We can see a lot more information about a specific user, we are much better positioned to judge if something is astroturfing or not.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the suggested edits being approved, especially with the tag wiki containing two obvious typos in the first sentence.

Comment: @Stijn: that's a good point too. We handed out some suspensions.

Comment: @Stijn The terrible suggested edit is what led me to check the history on the tag's wiki, which led me to post this question. I agree that whoever accepted those edits in the first place should have their knuckles rapped.