# Ad [astro]⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-disambiguation

The tag [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) seems to be ambiguous in its usage at best. It is used:

- to refer to the [Astro](https://docs.astro.build/en/getting-started/) static site building framework
- as a synonym of the [astrojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astrojs) tag (which is *also* used for the former, but only has [3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astrojs) currently)
- on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67919980/11407695) about SQL that has nothing to do with "astro" (?)
- to refer to the [astroalign](https://github.com/quatrope/astroalign) Python module for aligning stellar astronomical images
- to refer to the [ASTRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro) file manager for Android
- as a synonym of the [astropy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astropy) tag, a common core package for Astronomy in Python
- on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153996/matlab-display-rgb-values-of-a-fits-image) about MATLAB Astronomy & Astrophysics Toolbox (MAAT)

Both its wiki and tag excerpt consist only of a single sentence added by the venerable [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9):

> Some sort of file manager for android

It is proposed to make the tag a synonym of one of the two tags it is often used with ([astrojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astrojs) or [astropy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astropy)) and to remove it from the second, as well as from unrelated questions. Optionally to create an [astro-file-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro-file-manager) tag, but I am not sure whether questions about it would be on-topic on Stack Overflow.

The tag only has [23 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) at the time of this writing, so it qualifies for the expedited burnination process too if need be.

Comment: I approve of the murder of this tag. Astro itself isn't on-topic, but most of the questions appear to be on-topic. They're just using astro as a meta tag for the source of a URI, but it's mostly irrelevant to the file explorer itself. The rest are incorrectly tagged, so quick burn it is

Comment: so we have a tag that was used and then questions teh tag removed, the removing of the tag may be correct, but clarifying tha´e tag and where it is anbiguos diversify the tag into multiple , would be the appropriate, sure if someone has a question he can create a new one, but burning is the wrong answer

Comment: @nbk: I'm not really sure what you're saying. If the tag were relevant and appropriate on a question, it could always be recreated in the future (unless it's blacklisted). But based on Zoe's comment, it seems like the tag is currently not being used in a way that justifies it continuing to exist as a tag.

Comment: Only because site search is so bad: *[What can we do about a tag that appears to be nothing more than astroturfing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358275/what-to-do-about-tag-that-appears-to-be-nothing-more-than-astroturfing)*

Comment: it says "status-completed", but it's not stated _which_ action was taken. It looks like it was made a synonym of `astrojs` but would be nice to mention this here!

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer it wasn't made a synonym. Zoe's comment says she burned it. Which means removing all instances.

Comment: @VLAZ Technically disambiguated, but yes. The tag got killed

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer I wrote this in a comment elsewhere, but this is a disambiguation request (see the [tag-disambiguation] tag). [status-complete] indicates a disambiguation was completed, which _is_ an action.

Comment: Hard to know whether the [tag-disambiguation] tag overrides the authors sentence "It is proposed to make the tag a synonym of one of the two tags it is often used with (astrojs or astropy) and to remove it from the second, as well as from unrelated questions." or not. I now learned the tag is what matters, not the prose :)