# "Ad [Astro]" is tagged [status-completed] but unclear which (if any) action was taken

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

I came across this 2 year old meta post [Ad [astro]⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416800/ad-astro) question that raises the question of what to do with the [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) tag.

The post is tagged with the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, but there is no indication of what action was taken. None of the proposed actions seem to have been taken as the tag continues to exist and the issues raised remain.

Is my reading of the meaning of [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) wrong, that some action was taken in line with the proposal?

Abdul suggested that the resolution was likely manual reassignment. As there are now 20 times more questions tagged [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) (400 vs 20), I have made a synonym request post: [Make [astro] a synonym of [astrojs], or blocklist [astro]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429276/make-astro-a-synonym-of-astrojs-or-vice-versa)

Comment: The tag only had 23 questions at that time according to the post. I believe Zoe probably just retagged all of them to remove the tag. If you look at the creation date of the tag it is a few months after the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag was added.

Answer (score 9):

> The post is tagged with meta tag [status-completed], but there is no indication of what action was taken.
> [ ...]
> Is my reading of the meaning of [status-completed] wrong, that some action was taken in line with the proposal?

Yes, you are reading it wrong. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) generally always refers to another tag on the post. In this case, it refers to [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation). A completed disambiguation means that the questions on the tag have been retagged to other tags. A disambiguation is an action, and it's indicated by the existence of both [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation).

> None of the proposed actions seem to have been taken as the tag continues to exist and the issues raised remain.

Actions were taken; [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) isn't used *before* something is actually done.

As [Abdul Aziz Barkat noted in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429275/ad-astro-is-tagged-status-completed-but-unclear-which-if-any-action-was?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment989132_429275), the current version of the tag was made after the disambiguation.

To be specific, the tag was re-created on <strike>2022-12-17</strike> [2022-08-25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73490136/expected-a-backslash-preceding-the-semicolon-in-tailwind-vite-with-astro) (10k link), after its removal on 2022-03-24, which is presumably how it went unnoticed until now. Due to the size of the tag, the next steps are a [burnination-request](/questions/tagged/burnination-request) and a [blacklist-request](/questions/tagged/blacklist-request); not a synonym, as "astro" does not unambiguously refer to [astrojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astrojs); see again [the original disambiguation request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416800/6296561), which explains the many meanings. A synonym was never an option due to the ambiguous meaning of "astro".

The tag creation process is really, really bad in general, and there are plenty of feature requests asking for various improvements to it to prevent these tags from appearing in the first place, but  that's an aside. Finding the FRs in question is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @Zoe! I did not realize that you had taken the action as I was naively expecting that to be somehow "officially" indicated as an answer or not as the first comment. I missed that the tag was recreated recently. The reason I thought synonym was an option is that the author suggested that: "It is proposed to make the tag a synonym of one of the two tags it is often used with (astrojs or astropy) and to remove it from the second, as well as from unrelated questions. " And having "status-completed" I naively assumed that's what was completed.