# Make [astro] a synonym of [astrojs], or blocklist [astro]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, synonym-request, blocklist-request

Tag [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) was burninated 2 years ago in [Ad [astro]⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416800/ad-astro). At that time there were only 23 questions tagged with it.

In the past 2 years, [astrojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astrojs) has become very popular, resulting in [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) being recreated and used on more than 400 questions to date.

I suggest [astrojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astrojs) be made a synonym of [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) or vice versa.

The overwhelming majority of questions tagged with [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) is about [astrojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astrojs).

While there is a synonym request, it has 0 votes, and I can't vote on it myself. Yet the number of tagged questions suggests some manual action could be beneficial here.

Update: I don't mind burninating and blocklisting [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) as Makyen suggests in their answer. That is still better than the current chaos.

Comment: Similar tags: [[tag:astropy]], [[tag:astronomy]]. and [[tag:astronomer]].

Comment: The [[tag:astronomer]] tag seems to be problematic for this synonym request - it's some service that wraps Apache Airflow. However, they call it "astro" for short in serveral places in the official site https://www.astronomer.io/ including an "Astro API" and "Astro CLI". The words "astro" and "astronomer" seem to be used almost interchangeably for the product. There were 4 questions tagger [[tag:airflow]] + [[tag:astro]] and all four actually meant Astronomer (I've edited them accordingly). This seems to be a potential confusion with a synonym in place for [astro]

Comment: From my understanding, if an ambiguous tag has been recreated after burnination, then the tag should be **blacklisted**, not be marked as a *synonym*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev in the two years since then, astrojs has become a lot more popular. But yes, either synonym or blacklisting.

Comment: Not to be confused with [astroturfing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358275/what-to-do-about-tag-that-appears-to-be-nothing-more-than-astroturfing) (of which there is currently a new round of in the [TDEngine tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdengine)).

Comment: Astro has been burninated - but _not_ blocklisted, resulting in it being recreated, now with 12 questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I disagree. We should not make [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) a synonym of [astrojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astrojs). The [reasons for the burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416800/3773011) of [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro) are still valid, primarily that it's ambiguous and could mean any of at least 7 different things.

We should burninate [astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astro), again, and then blacklist it or otherwise prevent users from adding it to posts.

Comment: Happy with that - as long as we don't have proliferation of synonyms that aren't officially linked!