# Request of an "Atoum" tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Atoum is a PHP test framework (An alternative to PHPUnit) that is getting popular.

A tag for [atoum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atoum) related posts would be greatly appreciated to better identify these posts, just like phpunit's tag is helping in identifying phpunit related questions.

Here's a link to atoum's documentation : http://docs.atoum.org/en/latest/

Here is an example of a question where an atoum tag would help : [Mocking a series of methods with atoum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530203/mocking-a-series-of-methods-with-atoum)

**Possible wiki entry for the atoum tag :**

> This tag is for questions about atoum, a programmer-oriented testing framework for PHP. It is a unit testing framwork aiming at being more simple, modern and intuitive.
>
> According to the [Atoum documentation][1]
>
> > atoum is a simple, modern and intuitive unit testing framework for PHP! It is completly standalone, everything is available and works out of the box.
>
> **Latest stable version:** 3.2.0 (September 7, 2017)
>
> **Homepage:** https://atoum.org/
>
> **Documentation:** https://docs.atoum.org/
>
> **GitHub:** https://github.com/atoum/atoum/
>
> **Installation via PHAR**
>
> ```
> $ wget http://downloads.atoum.org/nightly/atoum.phar
> $ php atoum.phar
> ```
>
> **Installation via Composer**
>
> For a global install execute:
>
> ```
> $ composer global require "atoum/atoum=^3.2"
> ```
>
> For a project, install add the following lines to your project's composer.json file:
>
> ```
> {    
>   "require-dev": {       
>     "atoum/atoum": "^3.2"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Or use the composer command:
>
> ```
> $ composer require --dev atoum/atoum
> ```
>
> [1]: http://atoum.org/

Comment: There are [only five questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=atoum+is%3Aquestion) about it where only one of them has been asked in the last 12 month.

Comment: It **did** get more popular in 2015 though, so that's something.

Comment: I don't understand, can you be more specific ?
In the post's accepted answer you are refering to I read this : "As an alternative, you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new meta discussion."

Comment: @Stijn It's not a duplicate, but it's obvious that OP needs to read the answer to that question and edit this question accordingly.

Comment: @Ceyfiroth According to [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/4284627) to the proposed duplicate, your question isn't a good tag request. Please read the bullet list at the end of that answer and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @Donald Duck I edited according to the answer, hopefully this will help.

Comment: I added the [atoum] tag, please propose an edit for the tag wiki.

Comment: Before pasting the proposal, a native speaker should check it. For example, "For a project, install add the following lines" sounds wrong. Also, capitalization of the word "atoum" should be consistent.

Comment: Please don't include information that's clearly dated, such as the last stable version, in the tag information. No-one's going to update that when a new version comes out.

Comment: @BDL I already edited the wiki entry, I made the capitalization consistent with the official documentation and modified the sentence you are referring to. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/atoum/info (Still awaiting peer review) Edit: And removed the version info

Comment: Chance for title "Splitting the [atoum]" missed.