# Inexistent tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I was asking a question, and I needed specific tags which doesn't exist, these tags are: [httpservletrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpservletrequest) and [httpservletresponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpservletresponse).

How can I add these tags to SO?

Comment: Have you read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work ?

Comment: @BDL in fact my question has two parts: how to do that and mentionning the need for a specific tags which are `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`

Comment: @BDL It's not a duplicate, but OP needs to read the answer to that question and edit accordingly.

Comment: If you read the duplicate, you'll note that your request doesn't fulfill the requirements for a tag request.

Comment: @ziMtyth You need to read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/4284627) (especially the bullet list at the end) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: As I understand I have to create a discussion and propose the new tags with arguments, I believe that answers my situation even if I don't really know how to do that ;D but thanks @DonaldDuck