# My first new tag, what's next?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've recently made my first new tag! This tag is [`raintpl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raintpl), created by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718967/variable-recieving-data-from-php-function-in-raintpl#comment82398539_47718967) on Stack Overflow.

I was curious about the implications of this. Like I said, I've never made a tag before. I wasn't sure if this was the right opportunity to make it or not either.

Upon doing a search after I created the tag, I realized there are **48** [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=raintpl) that contain the word "raintpl".

Should these other questions have the tag added to them?

Comment: Related: [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work). I'm not sure if you should go on a mass edit spree.

Comment: @Stijn I've seen a question on here before about someone creating a tag and mass editing questions before, but the difference with that question was that the tag was not a good one.

Comment: Well, you'd better tag some more because the question you tagged was deleted.  Tags without questions get destroyed after a day.  It has been around a long time, check out [this pearl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582489/is-the-raintpl-template-engine-good?rq=1).  It is a bit odd that it didn't have a tag for the past 8 years.

Comment: @HansPassant So is it okay for me to tag other questions regarding it?

Comment: Pick the good ones.  Not the one I linked, it shouldn't be easy to find back.

Comment: If you are going to tag some questions, please make sure that you fix other issues with the post as well.

Comment: @honk Will do!.

Comment: So, you felt like you needed to create a tag, yet you didn't care enough to fill out the wiki with at least a little basic info about it? Very nice. Respekt.

Comment: @Will Huh? I did though. It said it was being peer reviewed?

Comment: I rejected the suggestions for the excerpt and the wiki, Please review the reject reasons and give it another go.

Comment: @rene Hi Rene. Not sure if I'm in the right place, but it still says the same thing for me. https://pasteboard.co/GXiOcgp.png

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18197963 and https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18197962