# Request for new tag / tag update - [gtag] for google's new version of google-analytics

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Google Analytics is transitioning to "gtag", and right now there isn't a tag specifically for this new implementation and naming convention. Since there are already numerous posts asking for help with the new system, some kind of edit / synonym to the `google-analytics` tag seems to make sense). See answers to [Combining Google Analytics (gtag.js) and Google Tag Manager (gtm.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932389/combining-google-analytics-gtag-js-and-google-tag-manager-gtm-js)

Is `gtag` too generic of a tag? Possibly. A synonym added to google-analytics might make the most sense.

Supposedly I have enough reputation to create tags, but I couldn't find the right place to do so.

Comment: Might want to read [this faq question and its answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/215552).

Comment: Helpful, thanks. (Still new to the procedures of intermediate stackoverflow-fu)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan what about adding a synonym, since gtag is mostly a renaming of the existing `google-analytics` tag, and used primarily for google analytics?

Comment: Sure. I changed the tags on this question to more closely match what you're asking about. I don't have enough domain knowledge to say what should happen with this specific tag/subject, so I'll leave it to people more knowledgeable than I. BTW, adding tags is as simple as editing a question and typing the tag into the tag area. If it doesn't exist, it will be created. You are encouraged to edit the tag info to explain how people should be using the tag.

Comment: I think [tag:google-gtag] would suffice.