# Creating a [tag] for a new API made by me

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it okay to create a new tag for a social networking website made by me, to tag all questions related to its developer tools like embedding, APIs, etc.?

Comment: read [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/578411) and then [edit] your question to address the points your request is currently missing. As it is currently stated I would say: No, it is not Okay. Also be aware of the guidance on [promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: I don't think that would be a promotion because the tag would be used for troubleshooting problems related to the API.

Comment: You need to address the post linked by rene... Also, note that there is a difference between questions related to programming with an API and support related queries of an API.. SO doesnt support the latter

Comment: @SurajRao I am talking about the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the guidelines stated at the top of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/3966682), to create a tag, the topic should be about a popular and/or established framework or library.

I am assuming your social networking site does not yet (or would ever) satisfy this requirement. Once it does and a large enough corpus of users start asking programming questions about your social network's developer tools, *then* and only then would it be appropriate to create a tag for it.

Comment: Well thank you! I suppose, a 2000 user base should be enough to make a tag for its developer tools, right?

Comment: How many people have actually created a question on SO about your platform? There should be a demand for the tag before you create a tag.

Comment: Well, I got it now. I would wait until my platform becomes considerably popular on SO. Thanks!

Comment: All the best with it (: