# Should we create [rasa-core] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

There is already a label for "Rasa-NLU", but they have extended their support with artificial intelligence and also created the "Rasa Core" project. I think it would be very interesting to have a Rasa Core tag.

This is the site: https://core.rasa.com

I believe that it is of fundamental importance to create the tag "rasa-core", but I do not have enough score for it.

If you search for "Rasa Core," you can see [approximately 25 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rasa%20core) about the topic without a really effective tag.

---

A list of questions about Rasa Core:

- *[Difference between Rasa core and Rasa nlu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818669/difference-between-rasa-core-and-rasa-nlu)*
- *[Understanding RASA-Core stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823632/understanding-rasa-core-stories)*
- *[How to use RASA NLU with RASA CORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700554/how-to-use-rasa-nlu-with-rasa-core)*
- *[Rasa-core, Slots not getting Populated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885628/rasa-core-slots-not-getting-populated)*
- *[For Rasa core and Rasa nlu, how should a reliable infrastructure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653135/for-rasa-core-and-rasa-nlu-how-should-a-reliable-infrastructure)*

Comment: Which question do you want to add that tag to? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work and then please update your question with the missing information.

Comment: Isn't that just covered by the [tag:rasa-nlu] tag?

Comment: @rene No. There are two distinct projects, both of which use artificial intelligence and are from the same company. One serves to identify the human writing, the other serves to generate a conversation context in a chatbot.

Comment: @Gimby You're right, sorry about that. I adjusted the description.

Comment: as a maintainer of both projects, I would love to see a separate tag for both so we can help developers better
https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core
https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu

Comment: @amn41 The tag has been created. =D