# Zappa tag with wrong use

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a lots of questions tagged with the **zappa** tag that are incorrectly tagged. Most of the questions refer to AWS lambda functions and Python, and they are also are tagged with **zappa**. This zappa refers to the [Python framework for AWS lambda](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa), not the actual tag [**zappa**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zappa/info) that refers to the [Node.js framework](https://zappajs.github.io/zappajs/).

So I think we need a new tag for the referring to the [**Zappa** Python framework](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa).

Comment: People use wrong tags all the time.  Not a bug.

Comment: Ah ok, Thanks. Can you create the tag?

Comment: There is only one Zappa, it's Frank.

Comment: But something like zappa-python-framework could be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I'm sure that Dweezil and Moon Unit would disagree with you.

Comment: @Makoto Is it really a duplicate? The answer says to do what the OP is doing now (although with more effort into arguing why it's needed)