# Reputation requirements for creating tags and tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-creation-process

My question, I believe, is straightforward:

What are the potential reasons for allowing people to create new tags when they reach the 1500 reputation threshold, but not suggesting tag synonyms until they hit the 2500 mark?

Given the important role that tags play on Stack Exchange, wouldn't it make more sense to first give people the opportunity to suggest synonyms for existing tags since these will have to go through a peer review process?

I am aware from other posts on Meta Stack Overflow that the process of approving tag synonyms is a long one and not exactly flawless, but that is not the point of my question.

I would be very interested in hearing your input on this.

Comment: It's worth noting (I think) that creating tags is a much lower-reputation privilege everywhere else on the network (300 rep - or 150 on beta sites -  rather than 1500)... So there's a much wider separation between the two...

Comment: Hmm, fairly sure it is 1500 vs 2500.  New tags are pretty easy to clean up, the machine automatically deletes them.  Synonyms can do more damage and are hard to get rid of, only a moderator can kill them.

Comment: Thanks, it is 1500 so i have corrected this now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Creating new tags simply means creating "a question in a topic that nobody before you (on this site, at least) ever has" [[Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)]. However there are so many tags right now that the majority of the questions all use pre-existing tags.

Furthermore, new tags don't last especially if they are rarely used, and don't do any harm to Stack Overflow. If a tag is wrongfully added, editors can simply remove that tag from the question. From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), it states:

> on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.

Tag synonyms, on the other hand, are much harder to clean up, and in case if a tag synonym is mistakenly used, many questions can be potentially affected, and only diamond moderators can fix them. Since the impacts of using tag synonyms can be considerable, it is reasonable that creating tag synonyms is a higher-reputation action than tag creation. Tag creation requires only 1500 reputation, but Tag synonyms require 2500 and at least 5 answer score on the involved tag.

Also, tag synonyms must be approved such that the it must have a net vote of 4 and never reach -2.

Comment: Both the question and this answer fail to mention that it takes a mere
 **5** in reputation to _suggest_ the creation of a new tag.
See the procedure described under
[_you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new **meta discussion**_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945).