# Should we create [nativescript-vue] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

Can you help me create a tag for [nativescript-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nativescript-vue)?

I've seen some questions about [nativescript-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nativescript-vue), but there doesn't exist a tag for it.

For example:

- [NativeScript-Vue Failed to find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194623/nativescript-vue-failed-to-find-module)
- [nativescript-vue audio module for vue-cli-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977895/nativescript-vue-audio-module-for-vue-cli-template)
- [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-sound'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502954/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-nativescript-sound)

Those questions should be tagged with [nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nativescript) / [nativescript-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nativescript-vue) and not with [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js).

Comment: What questions _need_ that tag? What should the tag wiki contain?

Comment: Here is some links (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194623/nativescript-vue-failed-to-find-module), (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977895/nativescript-vue-audio-module-for-vue-cli-template), (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502954/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-nativescript-sound) because they are tagging `vue.js` which is not appropriate. Those questions should be tag for `nativescript/nativescript-vue` and not for `vue.js`

Comment: Please follow the advises given [in this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work).