# Requesting a safe-node-app tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

To address the topics needed to be addressed by [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)

**Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate**

- So far it's just this one:
  [How to disable webpack dev server auto reload for neutrino project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073138/how-to-disable-webpack-dev-server-auto-reload-for-neutrino-project)
- Other SAFE network question are still almost exclusively asked on their forum.

**Explain why the tag and such questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow**

- Anyone can build a site or application for this network and thus use the [SAFEnetwork's API](http://docs.maidsafe.net/beaker-plugin-safe-app/) .

**Explain how the tag helps in categorizing and finding those questions**

- You will know that this person has issues with the safe network and not with the regular one.

**Provide an initial tag excerpt and wiki for the new tag, see here.**

If you are familiar with the decentralized web featured in the Silicon Valley television series then you already know what the SAFE network.

The SAFE network is reinventing the internet as it is a decentralized data network that allows people freedom of expression, share and store content in a private and secure way without being censored, surveiled or personal information being stolen, or collected without consent.

The SAFE Network will replace corporate servers (like Facebook data centers) with a peer-to-peer network (or “p2p”, like file torrenting), where all of humanity’s data can be spread out and securely backed up across everyone’s computers using spare storage space.

It was invented a couple years before Bitcoin was announced, and it doesn’t use blockchains at all — so there are no scaling problems (websites and data actually get faster as more people use and cache them); coin transactions are instant (rather than simply “fast”); and there are never any transaction fees for sending coins.

It’s free to browse this new internet, but you’ll pay a nominal amount (fractions of pennies) for uploading data. You’ll also get paid for hosting other people’s data; assuming you offer up enough storage, the fees cancel out and you end up with unlimited cloud backup for all of your files.

A working Alpha version is already available.

Credit goes to:

- Kevin Cooper from [medium.com](https://medium.com/safenetwork/safe-network-in-90-seconds-b00a5af31526)
- tobbetj from the [safe network forum](https://safenetforum.org/t/can-someone-give-me-a-good-elevator-pitch-for-the-safe-network/25204).

**Propose a good fitting name for the tag as they are always lowercase, don't take spaces and have a maximum length of 35 characters.**

- safenetwork?

---

[SAFEnetwork/Maidsafe](https://maidsafe.net/)

The safe network is a decentralized hosting network by splitting copying and spreading data files around its servers.

This means that no one server holds your files if you were to host a site on the network and thus can't "own" them.

To compensate for those who host data on the network, they are rewarded with Maidsafe's cryptocoin called SAFEcoin that relies on the same network.

The safe network is currently in its alpha stage.

I'm a simple programmer currently creating a simple website on this network, as I see all the advantages the safe network has to offer. 
To me the safe network means, I build a site, I press upload and presto, our site is on the internet. That includes server side web applications like forums as well. No internet hosting services needed. No maintaining your own server computer. No expensive domain registrars. No fear of DDOS attacks. And  no one else but can touch your site or your domain.
So it has all the good stuff from hosting a site on your own server without having to maintain it yourself.

I have recently come across my first issue relating to Peruse to ask in Stack Overflow.

Perhaps I'm early with this, but I expect many more issues to come with these two projects and not just from me.

Comment: Start by reading [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/7296893) (this link is more SO-specific than the one by yivi). At the bottom of the answer, there's a short list of things your question should include.

Comment: Also note, that Maidsafe is the name of a company, not of a product. That should definitely not be a tag. The SAFE network also doesn't seem to be on-topic on SO. It's a network infrastructure not a programming thing. peruse might be fine.

Comment: Also `safe-network` is **ambiguous** and so not a good option for a tag.

Comment: It sounds like you stole the plot from [Silicon Valley](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silicon-valley).

Comment: That's because Silicon Valley stole the plot from the SAFE network. https://spectrum.ieee.org/view-from-the-valley/telecom/internet/where-is-hbo-silicon-valleys-real-pied-piper-look-in-troon-scotland

Comment: Nice edit to answer the questions of the linked Q&A. Unfortunately, that tag wiki sounds like marketing speak. It doesn't tell me when I should use the tag, which is what a wiki and excerpt should do.

Comment: Good edit. But imho "safenetwork" is still off-topic. It's networking, not programming. Only the API would be on-topic, however this API is called.